# When is the right time and the wrong time to do the quick and dirty solution?

Tags: coding-style

When is it the right time and when is it the wrong time to take the quick and dirty approach versus the proper elegant solution?

This started from the comments on my question: [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java).

I wanted a way to do something using only internal Java or something I wrote. The only built in way is to use the sun.* package which is unsupported. So when is it the right time and when is it the wrong time to take that approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In any situation, you have to balance the time that will be spent on solving the problem, and then the time that will be spent in maintaining that solution. If the lifetime of whatever you do is expected to be lengthy, then the extra time spent up front to do things the right way will, presumably, be easier to maintain and will save you in the long run.

However, if there are time constraints, the penalties for going over may far outweigh the maintenance cost. For example, if you MUST get a product out the door, do a quick-and-dirty solution now, and then log it as a bug to get fixed later in a patch, or the next version. That will require you to re-do the work, but like I said, it is all a balancing act, and often driven by cost at it's root.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion the only "right time" to use a quick and dirty solution (aka hack) is when...

1. There is a mission-critical bug that needs immediate fixing and the proper solution is significantly complicated to implement.
2. It's an internal application and some higher ups need a quick feature implemented (hey, neither you nor your customers use it).

Answer (score 4):

The right answer is that its *never* time to do the quick and dirty solution.
But sometimes (when having a big customerbase and lots of programs out there) its better to ship a fix with a Q&D that maybe breaks something, but FOR SURE fix more.

I dont know if I understand the question right but Ill leave it with this.

Answer (score 3):

If there exists a simple but less elegant solution that closely matches the style and techniques used elsewhere in the code base (and consequently, is more easily understood by your colleagues), it may be safer to take that path -- compared to the solution that is perfect from an academic point of view, but difficult to understand if you never happened to read that specific paper.

Similarly, a small change may be considerably safer than a major refactoring effort that the elegant solution would basically require. This is especially relevant in any world that lacks unit tests.

Comment: Good point about code-base consistency.

Answer (score 3):

If the project is a "proof of concept" work rather than a production implementation, it may be the right time for a quick and dirty solution that gets the job done of illustrating how easy or hard some particular part is of a system.  I'm thinking of where one may want to test out a new ERP or CRM system and just want to see the mechanics of it without spending a ton of time and money to get a more realistic prototype working.

In most other cases, it is a question of trade offs.  How many defects can something have that gets released into the wild?  Are just no showstoppers bugs OK or does there have to be few only a few minor or cosmetic bugs left.  If some project managers or business units want something quick but not necessarily fully working then it the quick and dirty solution may work if those asking understand the risks.  In a way this is like the question of how many tests should a doctor give before making a diagnosis:  Should you be examined head to toe through a variety of different waves of energy, e.g. X-ray, CT scan, MRI, etc.  Or can the doctor just look at what you are doing and know what is wrong like Dr. House does from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that quick and dirty solution is more often necessitated by a lack of planning somewhere moreso than it is because of a sudden change of business rules (not to say that doesn't happen though!).  Either someone wasn't given appropriate tools to do their job, someone vastly underestimated the amount of time something will take, or someone got too attached to a feature that is overly complicated.  In most of those cases, it's best to push back your release or scale back the features in the release.

In the case that it *was* necessitated by a business priority that you have no control over (like a legal issue), then you need to get it out the door as quickly as possible.  But you should make the fix better for the next release!

Answer (score 2):

It's the right time to use a quick and dirty solution when:

- You need the solution to be quick (assuming no professional solution exists that is approximately as quick), and
- You don't suffer consequences for it being dirty.

In some ways, that's a flippant answer, but it does cover it.

In your situation, you can't introduce a new library quickly.  And you do have a process to mitigate the risk of using experimental code.  As long as that process is reliable, and you are confident that production code won't include your quick & dirty solution, then go ahead.

Once my company was struggling to get some code working for a demo at a trade show.  They were running out of time, the demo just one day away.  I suggested they hard-code some options instead of making them configurable and dynamic.

It worked -- they got the demo running for the next day's show.  Then when they got back to the office, they *immediately* removed the hard-coded part and finished their feature.

If you can rely on replacing the quick & dirty hack being *top priority*, then quick & dirty can be appropriate.  It's just so seldom the case that it's top priority, that using this solution is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by tj111 and others, there are times when the *risk* of an elegant solution are greater than that of the quick and dirty. I.e., you deliver something beautiful, but by that time the customers no longer want it, want something different, or are pissed off.

To be sure though, there is always a long-term cost with doing a quick and dirty solution and it is important to deliver a firm and forceful "by the way" caveat to management. Else the quick and dirty becomes like crack to management who often do not know or care of the difference between the elegant and dirty (especially when it is under the hood). That is until things start to go to hell, and even then the fixitnow stress is offloaded to the hapless (often new) technical team.

So yeah, sometimes you have to do it because of $$ and time considerations, but don't cloak it or forget it and strive and push to re-factor soon when the crisis wanes.

Answer (score 2):

Remember a lot Application get built off of their prototypes.

We always want to think its throw away code.  But it will grow!

Answer (score 1):

In my case I work in a research and development position where we have a long process for getting approval when adding external libraries.

If code is marked as experimental it will be cleaned up before moving to production. I needed this for a quick experiment to see if something was even going to make sense for us to work on and needed to get the data processing quickly. So the quick and dirty approach was the right one to get things done asap. If we decide to work on the experiment I will have time to replace the functionality properly.

In the standard case where as kdgregory put it in the comments of one answer:

> Bzzt. In a professional environment,
>   using an unsupported, undocumented
>   feature is never the correct decision.
>   And in a corporate environment,
>   "experiments" become "production code"
>   with no chance to fix the hacks.

I think he is correct that it is not the appropriate approach when you work in a position where you have even a doubt that it may go into production. The only exception with this is if you absolutely do not have the time for a proper fix but can mark it as being a high priority issue in some visible public place (bug tracker) and will definitely be able to fix it in a future release.

Comment: Working with R&D is my dream. It is, from my side of the garden, the greenest grass you can get. ;)

Comment: Sounds like your process is broken if it would prefer you to use undocumented, unsupported code in lieu of a robust and well supported third party library.

Comment: When things need approval through security, which takes time, it is not necessarily a broken process. As I stated this is for an experiment, and if the results are not fruitful we will not be working on it. If they are promising there will be the time to use the library, so how is this broken?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a quick and dirty solution is synonymous with an unmaintainable solution.  Other times it just means solving the (simple) problem you actually have, not the (more complex) generalization of that problem.  I'm a grad student doing research in bioinformatics and I often need to write small programs that do simple things like reformat or summarize a few hundred megs of data.  Occasionally I need to write several of these apps **per day**.  If I wrote "proper" solutions to these I'd never get anything done.

Solving the general case (not quick and dirty) would mean making an app that handled errors robustly, was usable by people other than me, was configurable, etc.  This would solve lots of problems that I don't have.  I'm probably the only one that will ever use these programs.  All the configurability I need is a few command line options and the ability to edit the source file as needed.  All the error handling I need is displaying a decent error message and exiting if there's a problem.

Of course, sometimes these programs do grow into something more important and sometimes I do end up reusing code from them.  Maintainability counts.  Even in a quick and dirty solution, magic numbers should not be hard coded, variables should not be named "foo", "bar", and "stuff", and programs should not be written as one giant 400-line `main()` function.  I learned these the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have to do things in Q&D way.  What you need to do in that circumstance is to protect yourself by hiding the dirty implementation behind an interface or an adapter.

To use the cited example, the Sun.* package works for now, but may not sometime in the future.  Fine.  Then wrap it in an adapter that implements the desired interface.  Then, when Sun changes the API (hopefully providing something permanent like Java.BASE64), you can quickly update your implementation to cope with the change.

Answer (score 0):

I do a quick and dirty fix when three conditions are met:

- There isn't enough time to do a proper solution
- The fix and it's scope are clear and contained (it's easy to come back, know what the fix addressed, can be easily removed and replaced by a proper implementation)
- The fix is atomic or has no dependencies

Answer (score 0):

"Quick and Dirty", is often synonymous with "cheap yet actually works", which is generally all you need to get the job done. If anybody criticizes your code, pretty much the best defence is to say "yeah- it was just a quick and dirty solution". That way your coder colleagues can feel superior to you, whilst you pointy haired boss looks on, rubbing his chin in silent approval.

Comment: "Quick and Dirty", is often synonymous with "cheap yet actually works".

This is false. It is much more often synonymous with "something nobody would want to maintain"

Comment: +1 for pragmatism.  Yes, maintainability counts, but another form of the quick-and-dirty solution is just one that solves your very specific case of a problem instead of worrying about the more general case.  If you likely will never need to solve the more general case, this can be a perfectly reasonable thing.