# Best API/LIB for encoding/decoding base64/quoted-printable in Java

Tags: java, base64, quoted-printable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode Base64 data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Thanks to everyone in advance,

I am aware of http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html etc, can anyone point to me another option preferably one that does not require me to use external libraries.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You might find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: I think the link above provides you with a solution for Base64 but not QP... you could probably piece the information together from multiple answers on Stackoverflow.  I don't believe this is a duplicate...

Comment: The thing to do in cases like this, is to ask a question that isn't already answered. So, post a question asking specifically for a library that'll en/decode quoted-printable. If you then accept Jon's, the combination of this and the linked question will provide a single solution for you or anyone wanting both.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use one from [iharder.net](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/)? It is fast and it is in public domain.

Comment: Just curious: why would you recommend this over Commons Codec (which is, at least, more widely used)?

Comment: It is small and completely free of any licenses. Commons codec is more like an all-purpose library, and this tiny library does only one thing and does it very well.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Sun's jvm you can use sun.misc.BASE64Encoder/Decoder but it's not Open Source:

```
final BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
final String encodedString = encoder.encode( "whateveryouhaveinmind".getBytes() );
```

Answer (score 0):

[migbase64](http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/) is the fastest (according to their benchmark).

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to answer this with some more information as people here seem to have missed your requirement for a utility for both **Base64** and **Quoted Printable**.

Take a look at MimeUtility in Javamail here:

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html

That provides encoding/decoding for both Base64 and Quoted Printable, amongst others, look at the decode method:

```
public static InputStream decode(InputStream is,
                                 String encoding) throws MessagingException
```

Commons Codec provides similar functionality in the form of QCodec and Base64, but no main method that I know of.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I too had the same requirement as the OP, but in my case, only for `quoted-printable`.  I tried `MimeUtility.decode(InputStream, encoding)` but I'm finding that it doesn't have support for *soft line breaks* (= ).  So decoded content is finally having soft line breaks included.  Any idea/solution?