# Can we convert a byte array into an InputStream in Java?

Tags: java, base64, inputstream

Can we convert a byte array into an InputStream in Java? I have been looking on the internet but couldn't find it.

I have a method that has an InputStream as argument.

The InputStream `cph` I have is base64 encoded so I had to decode it using

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(cph);
```

Now how do I convert `decodedBytes` again to `InputStream`?

Comment: The "Use" link at the top of API doc pages is very useful for these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

Use [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
```

Answer (score 187):

[`java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) extends `InputStream` to do exactly this:

```
InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(myBytes);
```

Answer (score 24):

It is [in the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html):

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { 0xC, 0xA, 0xF, 0xE };
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use [Robert Harder's Base64 utility](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/), then you can do:

```
InputStream is = new Base64.InputStream(cph);
```

Or with sun's JRE, you can do:

```
InputStream is = new
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.packaging.mime.util.BASE64DecoderStream(cph)
```

However don't rely on that class continuing to be a part of the JRE, or even continuing to do what it seems to do today. Sun say not to use it.

There are other Stack Overflow questions about Base64 decoding, such as [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Comment: Don't use the sun class it's private and should not be used as it can change at anytime.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include dire warnings. The code in the question is already using `BASE64Decoder` which is presumably `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to **convert byte[] to InputStream using Guava library** as well.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>



    public static void guavaConversion() throws IOException{
       byte[] bytesArray = {1, 2, 3};
       InputStream inputStream = ByteSource.wrap(bytesArray).openStream();

       System.out.println(inputStream.toString().getBytes().length); //just 
       //for testing
       inputStream.close();
    }
```