# Uploading byte array to FTP in Java

Tags: java, ftp, upload, apache-commons-net

My goal is to be able to upload files to FTP server, I have researched a bit and saw the way how to upload a file if the file is already stored locally, I have a function that returns `byte[]` so I am wondering how to send that file to FTP server if it file exist in memory.

```
private void connect() throws IOException {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
    ftpClient.connect(ftp.getServer(), ftp.getPort());
    int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
    if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftpClient.disconnect();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not connect to FTP Server");
    } else {
        ftpClient.login(ftp.getUser(), ftp.getPassword());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using Apache Commons Net [`FTPClient`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

It actually does not even have a direct way to upload a *physical file*. Its [`FTPClient.storeFile` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#storeFile(java.lang.String,java.io.InputStream)) only accepts [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) interface.

Normally you would use `FileInputStream` to refer to a physical file:
[How do you upload a file to an FTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6527664/850848)

While you want to to use `ByteArrayInputStream`:
[Can we convert a byte array into an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1802123/850848)

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ftpClient.storeFile(remotePath, inputStream);
```