# Upload string to a file on FTP server in Java

Tags: java, xml, ftp

I want to put a file to FTP address automatically in a scheduler.
I have a JSON object so I can create an XML from this.
I can create a `xmlString` with a code below.

I want to put the XML in the `xmlString` to a file `abc.xml` at an FTP address. How I can do it?

```
private static String objToXml(Object object) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(object.getClass());
    Marshaller marshallerObj = context.createMarshaller();
    marshallerObj.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    marshallerObj.marshal(object, sw);
    return sw.toString();
}

String xmlString = "";
try {
    xmlString = objToXml(anObject);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to store a string to a file on an FTP server.

- Convert your string to an `InputStream`:
  [How do I convert a String to an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/782178/850848)
- and then upload it:
  [Uploading byte array to FTP in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61231580/850848)

```
byte[] bytes = xmlString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ftpClient.storeFile(remotePath, inputStream);
```

---

*Having that said, most XML libraries are be able to write directly to an `OutputStream`, sparing the necessity (and memory waste) of the intermediate `String` object.*

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. I was thinking an other way. This is very simple :)