# Is there a way to "send" a file over FTP from a server without exposing the local file system?

Tags: java, ftp, filesystems

I have my desired file in memory on my server. I need to send it over FTP, i cant use anything else for it. I dont want to store the file on my sever and then expose the folder. Is there a way to send over FTP from memory?

Comment: What you mean by "in memory"?

Comment: Yes you can send things directly from e.g an in-memory  byte array, see here for example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231580/uploading-byte-array-to-ftp-in-java

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I mean in the RAM of my Server. Basically I will get it somewhere else and I cant store it on the local filesystem. I wan to send it directly

Comment: @Arnaud this is an example for an ftp client. I need code for a server that waits for incoming requests