# How download a String with p:fileDownload?

Tags: java, primefaces

```java
String output = "qwerty123";
```

Then how to export that string to
`StreamedContent` in PrimeFaces ?

you can see the example here : https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml?jfwid=e2fc5

In that link, the `StreamedContent` exported from `.jpg` collected from resources in Web Pages Directory.
But in my case, I just want to convert the string above `output` to `.txt` then stream it in `StreamedContent` without `Files.write();`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ByteArrayInputStream` to stream the contents of your string:

```java
DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
        .name("your.txt")
        .contentType("text/plain")
        .stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream("qwerty123".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
        .build();
```

See also:

- [How to convert Java String into byte[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571223/how-to-convert-java-string-into-byte)
- [Can we convert a byte array into an InputStream in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802123/can-we-convert-a-byte-array-into-an-inputstream-in-java)