# How do I encode/decode short strings as Base64 using GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, base64

I need to encode a short String as base 64 in GWT and decode the base 64 string on the server. Anyone have utility class or library for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode Base64 data in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Comment: People should start noticing that a GWT question probably has a different context from Java SE and is not a duplicate of a Java SE question. What runs on Java SE requires additional treatment to be placed on GWT.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use native JavaScript for this on the client on all browsers except IE ≤ 9. On the server you can use [one of the official classes](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/135).

Java/GWT:

```
private static native String b64decode(String a) /*-{
  return window.atob(a);
}-*/;
```

Encode is `btoa`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the BaseEncoding class provided by Guava.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html

For example:

```
try {
  String encoded = BaseEncoding.base64().encode("foo".getBytes("UTF-8"))
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  GWT.log(e.getMessage());
}
```

And don't forget to add the following line to your GWT module XML:

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.io.Io"/>
```

The BaseEncoding class can be used on both the GWT client side and server side.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at https://github.com/mooreds/gwt-crypto

It provides base64 encoding to GWT.

```
Base64.encode(string.getBytes());
```

Add the import below :

```
import com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;
```

Don't forget to add the following line to your GWT module XML:

```
<inherits name="com.googlecode.gwt.crypto.Crypto"/>
```

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.gwt-crypto</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-crypto</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 class can't be used on the client side. It would have to be emulated.