# "decoder.decodeBuffer" doesn't produce the expected output when decoding base64 read from a file

Tags: java, base64

When I plug this into an on-line decoder utility (https://www.base64decode.org/) it produces the expected outcome:

```
yLContent-Type: multipart/related; boundary="=_related 00615E8385257E0C_="
This is a multipart message in MIME format.
 /--=_related 00615E8385257E0C_=
Content-Type: text/html; charset="US-ASCII"
<font size=1 face="sans-serif">This is rich text</font><font size=3> </font>
<p><img src=cid:_1_170D5344170D4F4400615E8385257E0C>
" q--=_related 00615E8385257E0C_=
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-ID: <_1_170D5344170D4F4400615E8385257E0C>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
R0lGODlhdgFcAOYAAOjw..................
```

When I try to convert using the following Java code

```
File mimecontent=new File("C:/temp/mimecontent.txt") ;//please see base64 text below
String instr=new String(FileUtils.readFileToString(mimecontent));
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(instr);
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes));
```

I get the bad output shown below

```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==
```

The text I'm trying to decode:

```
AgACAAAAAQB5AAAATAAAAAAAAABDb250ZW50LVR5cGU6IG11bHRpcGFydC9yZWxhdGVkOyBib3Vu ZGFyeT0iPV9yZWxhdGVkIDAwNjE1RTgzODUyNTdFMENfPSINCg0KVGhpcyBpcyBhIG11bHRpcGFy 
dCBtZXNzYWdlIGluIE1JTUUgZm9ybWF0Lg0K
AgADAAAAAgDTACAALwAAAAAAAAAtLT1fcmVsYXRlZCAwMDYxNUU4Mzg1MjU3RTBDXz0NCkNvbnRl bnQtVHlwZTogdGV4dC9odG1sOyBjaGFyc2V0PSJVUy1BU0NJSSINCg0KPGZvbnQgc2l6ZT0xIGZh 
Y2U9InNhbnMtc2VyaWYiPlRoaXMgaXMgcmljaCB0ZXh0PC9mb250Pjxmb250IHNpemU9Mz4gPC9m b250Pg0KPHA+PGltZyBzcmM9Y2lkOl8xXzE3MEQ1MzQ0MTcwRDRGNDQwMDYxNUU4Mzg1MjU3RTBD Pg0K
AgADAAAAAgD7IiAAcQAAAAAAAAAtLT1fcmVsYXRlZCAwMDYxNUU4Mzg1MjU3RTBDXz0NCkNvbnRl bnQtVHlwZTogaW1hZ2UvZ2lmDQpDb250ZW50LUlEOiA8XzFfMTcwRDUzNDQxNzBENEY0NDAwNjE1 RTgzODUyNTdFMEM
+DQpDb250ZW50LVRyYW5zZmVyLUVuY29kaW5nOiBiYXNlNjQNCg0KUjBsR09E bGhkZ0ZjQU9ZQUFPancrRWlvWUFDSVVCQ1lXQmlZYUFpUVlEaWdXQWlnY0FDUWNFQ3dTQ2lnYU9E 
NHdQLy8vemlnWU1Ebw0KcUFpUVVOajR1SmpRa0JpWVlKalFpQ0NZWUhqQWdIakFjSWpJbUhDNGtM amdzTkR3dVBENDhJalFtR0M0ZUJpWVdEQ2dXRUNvWU9qdw0KNkxqb3NHQ3dpQ2lnV0RpZ2VIaTRt 
SWpBaUpEUWtCQ2dhSmpJc0tqWW1ORHdzSkRJaU1qb3NKakFzS0RRdUxqZ29LRFlvTkRvMkNDWQ0K ZURpZ1VGQ3djR0N3Y05qbzRDaW9lSkRJa01qd3NGaXdhR2lvaUhqQWtMRFlvTGpvcUJpZ1dFQ29h 
QUNRV0FpUVdDQ2dXTGpZeUZpdw0KZ01Eb3NBQ1lhQWlZV0dDNGlIQzRnSWk0b0xqZ3FEQ2dZRWlv Z05EZzJDQ1lXR0NvY0ZDd1VMRFlxRENnYUVDb1NFQ29VTERncUFDSQ0KWUFDUVVCQ1FVQkNRV0ND 
UVlFQ1ljRUNvY0Vpb2VKalFvR0M0V0dpNG9IQzRlSGl3bUhpNGdJRElrTERnbUxqUXdBQ0lXQ0NR V0ZpZw0KZ0lqQW9JakllSWpJZ0lqSWtKRFFnSmpJcUtqSXVNRFkwQUNRYUFDWWNDaVlXQ2lnWUVD 
b1dIakFpSmpRdUFDUVlBQ2djQkNZWUN3QQ0KQUFBQWRnRmNBRUFJL3dBQkNCeElzS0RCZ3dnVEts eklzS0hEaHhBalNweElzYUxGaXhnemF0eklzYVBIanlCRGloeEpzcVRKaVFKUw0KcWt4cElJRExs 
ekJqeXB4SnM2Wk5sd2x5NnR6SnM2ZlBuMENEWG5seUFJSFJvMGlUS2wzS3RLbFRveTF2U3AxS1ZT YUlxbGl6eXFUUQ0KcDREWHIyRERmaDJ5c3F6WnMyakxZalRiWU1FTkJ5dGU4bGpoSUVZTHVYVHR2 
cnp4dzhHUE1pNGpPSEJaSVFaY0hpNWJWSUFUbzh4Yw0KQnc0aVBCbWdRd01RSFFNZU5KaFE5NDFQ QzJrY3BMR1EwOEdFQkJQRzVKUUQrWFNDTWFsRHA2R0Ntb1ZwblZpZUtFQUJlWVVRQlhHVw0KSEJp 
T1J2aUJDeGt5WEtCeEZMbHk1Z2hvSUsrQzRTaUdLaGxrUURIcVhBeDBveU11TlA4ZllSVEtDUkFS YnJSd29DRjlCYmQ5ZnlEVw0KV2hWRWtBSDQ4eitRUXIvL1RBb1VFQ0RnZ0FKS0lOYUJDQ1lZRmxs 
cG5iVVdXaC80cDFVRCtWVm9vWDRwUFJIVWhoemlwc0NISUlZbw0KNG9jcERHZmlpU2dlNE1kVExM Wm9sQllxUlNnaFZoUmVhR05tTE0wNFZZQUU5dWdqQVFZcUtPU1FCM3BRd3dkY29QV2dTZ3NzY0lJ 
QQ0KSnl6d0F3Uk5TaGxZbFF2c3NNQmdEaXdRQVdGTkJ0QUNsZ3VnUVJtV1FIU3dBQkFyTkJuREFq SGdKMFNUTnFqa3hKWThXV0NCYWhQZw0KU1VXWFZiSkFtZ1ZONnZGaGx5Z29zQWVWVGJyUXBJaHRR 
b0JDQndxVWFLSVlXRUtBeG5BaUxNREJFazJhMkNseVdGNHdRcE5HK2NCbw0KazJJWWxjRUNNbUQv ZVlZQVo1QjVubzR3ZlhEanJoYytVRlpVRWdMNDQ3REVBdWtWQThpR2hTd0RYeTFMUnJQTE12QXNH 
ZEV5ME1DMQ0KMkRaZ3dMYmNJcG5Ta2cybTlBQ3dBVlJRd1V4bG5GdUVoVUowWUFPdk51YlJaQVg0 K1hyV0ZHd1lzS0VGRmZ3V29oQk0yRENpQWgwdw0KNGUvQUg5ckFCQk01cEhqRUVtQ2thR0lPRUV0 
OG9sSWxqTEFkVWpDaTFjQVVBWlExTGxicndtdXlqZmFlNVlGVXdoYnJzc3NTVkp1cw0Kek5VK1cr MjFKakJnd3JVM1h3dUR0dHdHdmUyU1h5QmJoeGxlbE5YRUJ0SFNJUUFHTkM4TE5RTmhEREFIc2tj 
TWNBR3lBeHpCOUxJaA0KaEFIMURFWndmVVFJeTI3UVJGbHFNTERCQzIyb1JNU0haUzg3QXhnS0lI dTEyd3dZLy9HaEcyN25yYk1DYzN6dDloeDBSenREd3lNWQ0KM3JmRmtFZCtRQkpyaEd2NVdTUUVZ 
Ti9Kbkp1Yzh1VmR2Q3o2Nk1ZUzZaV1JRcWV1K3Vxc2c2dFNEejNFWGRZWHNWLytRT2RXWUZDMQ0K eVdHTUlEdGF0UGVRZEZtd0QwOEVBUWduLytFU0pod3hvZ2tZTkh4aURtU1FJVG5rU1RCNCtmYmNt 
M1Y3NStCLzNyMVpSUHhCK3VoQg0KaW9VNjYreTM3LzVKOE1jdi8vejAxMi8vL2ZqbnIvLysvUGZ2 Ly84QURLQUFCMGpBQWhyd2dBaE1vQUlYeU1BR092Q0JFRHdJV25CRg0KUVplQW9HUVB3RUtITnNq 
Qm53d2xSSlk2d0IxY1JNSVNMc1VPRmFUZ0JldEZyaFJxcFdVRk1wME10VGMrbGJqdUIyUnlTMlJr c3NPWQ0KU0NrQ1FBUmlBUDhFODU0Z0F2RXVQYnlCQmx5Z0F6UkVBQWo0dVF4K25PQ0VDRXpnaXFu 
WnlRSkl3NVBiYkhFQ0xNRGlGZlcwQUowUQ0KcWpRVHlJMkliSUNDTEN6QUJRcHdBQWRFeFFFT2lP QkVLMEtPVXBKemdUNzJzUVRSOFlFTUlBQUJRSmJnQWxWWUFCS1NBZ1VJSUVBRA0KSlpEQkJYendB 
d0ZJWVFIbkVneVlYdkllRjJydVBydnlWUXM5dVJYUnBVK0dxRHdRRFIxMGtiS2M0QVJUU0VubXBG S0JDTndsS3dZQQ0KSDRaU01vQXJKT0FObkltQUhIWmlnUWtNczRNQkdCZ2JFeldpT0dUQkFWbmdR 
TVFraDRaUG1XaEZUam1rZUV4b0I3UE1rcFFCeUtVdQ0KY1pRU1BKQ1NSK2NiVU14a1ZvQ29TUXRh MFZKV3o3RFZMUStvcFpVcmFkS1RvdVQvQkFHc2JGNWQrdEtWdU9RbE1DMGdBQ1RJQXhwVw0KUUNV 
STVHRUFhbG9BZmlKYUlUVkI0RDB1SUtjQUlyQUFGckNCQXI2a1FwTk8weWNIRUtxTU9na29FeDUx cUFXZ0FBVmJBdEZLRnlBaQ0KeUZDS1JJN2lRSk9NY3dDZDNyRlRud29WcHp6VjB3VmtBRHlvZXRV 
MkVYQ3FCU0JBcVhaWXd4U2FsQkkybkNFQ0RXWER5aVJFZ25HRw0KOGl3eXdnb00wMG1zSUMxTG5q SjdGanpiR2EwR0xDdGI5RlFka2x6M0JUcEVJUXAwTUlQS0doQ1RFOEFBQnB2emF1ZkVwN1E2M0xV 
Sw0KSGRCSkE1VEgyTDg2ajdHVnVwNWtKYmVVanRWUUpSN2c2MHdDSzlpVEVkWXNtWVhKV01sS3Vs T2ljbjN1UzIzUWx0UUV2SzdFRE1pSw0KQWdOZThEcGsvNlVFV1NOUXdnQ1FoWUg4TUEwR0RMZ0Fj 
SUU3QS95Z2JRWXF3TUFNR0pCY3J1RkhCUXdJZ1FwVThJTHFyazBsZC8yZA0KQUhBd1cyU3A0YS9n UFFLeVRBQWl3SVdnYkg0VG5BbVdDd01RTVE4TXlETENYL2xBWHlnTXh3MHdRSnUwSm91OXkvcDND 
N3J0N0dEOQ0KUzRRQ2tQWjhwaTFTRFZUTFlQYTV6ci9jZTBDQU8vdFpDSnZGd0pCTlhnajVhNklr OU1IQ0lJYXdoQVdzMFJDZmhRaGRrTUNCVDRuYQ0KQnJ1NGZSR01zWXhuVE9NYTIvakdPTTZ4am5m 
TTR4NzcrTWRBRHJLUWgwemtJaHY1eUVoT2N2M1FjaFZ3U3FnSUQvQmxCNmRNNVE5Rw0KZG9RbXpI S1c3ZEJrSi9jSHlsMzJjbFZhbHVCVUZtQ1ZJSDR3cmJaVVFVM1N4LzgrRVRCVFp2UTFaUzl5a1lQ 
QzdJa2FSYlJoRVdyNQ0KejAvUlFnQXdLYWE0bE91Z1lvNEpaek1UMWtUWFpMU2xNL09RMEx5OUI3 UGdEQi9nd1FMdUVvRWR2SVF4US9TMFMwQWRBNEVPTVFaRA0KSE14Rlg3SkRCMEFBTVdVWWpIMTBB 
TVVCU0hFQWNYQ0NsQzBBQVo2VVdpZFhUSUNkZVUyYkJGQUJBbVRrNGhtRjdabzl3eVZoaVpJag0K SFkrd2dJYjVvUVFaS0FFVUZnQWRiQi95cU9CeDVBV1FBSjBMWUZzR1JqbGtValFnSGg5a3dKRUlR 
QUttQ2UzbTk1enIwT0JjZElVZQ0KOEFCSC93ZWRQeXF6cENkZGFYeW01QVFzRUpkTFZxQ0JJZ2Jn Qmp2NGtzTWgvaVU0ckJyaVAwaDFBRmF3Z3h1VUN3SkkvRklEVUtBQg0KSVVBVUFyWC9Ca0lFNUFT 
Qk9GeUJDbWxnQVU4bWdPd0U4Sm8wZGs3QURtYURtZ1dNWWRrMlIrbXphNXFGMzZ6VUJpdHdRY04w eW9FYw0KUUVBR09jaUJETzVJZzZmVGdBWXlPR29KSUNBZXJHc0FBUmVBSkFKS29BRjNWNEU1cHdJ 
a1VzU2dBWFRUWUFFUVlJTUFIa0J2VVhkeQ0Ka3hXc0VieDh0VlZIQXh4bUF3KzhWNGlRRmpXbnBB dU8xanZuVXFZSEtuTXdtUm5tTTRkVkJHZ1hkVk1saUUrMDRqMmJFaTU0K2Uvbw0KRTN3cVc0d0h3 
cnBPbnlvWnBVdzRPcGlxNkFxaVRRcWZTdGpnS0FoTW9KaFVrbm5QSGNCQlF5RnNwaUtDYWN1WkVB ZEhhVUJ5UUUwUg0KVWk1Z1ZLUFFZQVRrTVdIbHpLSjZIYjNlcTU5cjlJd2duYzUxVm91dDdyUlov 
N1g0OEJVK3lBeXVRaXU5RFEyZUV0UkhpUVVyMHpRbQ0KMjlUNkFPQ1FvQUo5ejBHcEZJTU9RTlQv c0NkUkFZZ1orRUVsOVBJbU9wQXkra1FDUDFGU0lyVkZPWEZzQy9BR0p3VWlpTElIY09jdg0KY2NC 
U0lZSjBxd0lyQjVCVG9ySUFZbkFBUUFVcUN6Q0NjOFI4NE5aVUNJQXA0QVoyaXZSVXNHSVVNeVVB VlBJRHNUUUZVOUIzTTlKVg0KSkZaaU9kSWYzTGRpeDVJc1lCRTFhbldFREdCKzBvSXN3SVVzY0hV 
dGNwVWtwK2NrVUxJQS9lUlA4M0lEVkJKeGI4Sm1iYklBSzhCUQ0Kc2FjQlpOZ0JPZ0IzRDJVRGpS SUJGRlVoSE5Va0QvVTVVUUozVHNBb3JsRlNQUWNCVnNRQ01UVW5iOFFiVFpJb3RZY0NZMGhUSVlL 
Qg0KY0FjWlRmK2lBUlRUSkRKZ1IzRFhNRUNWQTQxQ2lVU2xVd3NnQWo3Z2dsVm5WQmNRS3d0QUhr cVZFbE8xQUFJQWlCRXdCVkVTZC80VQ0KWmxVQmhFRzRTMlpoVGxSUmhBZW1Ua3lJVnZDMGhNc2lB 
ZDdITTFJNGhhenpBWWFYRnQ5a0V5VkRZaEhsQXU5U0wrRWlCVkxXRXlBUQ0KZWRnNEluMDJlZGZq RkZIbFg4dFlFODFZaXhaU1lURkNFN3E0aXozaWZmRVVmdkJVakc2RkxmUDBNdzVtY0Y3QU5IVUFP 
M1NBTE5kVg0KRnJnWUFML1ZXN3hGamlpREZpL2dOazNRQTAzQVhTR3dXTm40UENhQU41QzFqZHc0 V1ZobVdTSDJqeFlFU2dSNUkrWllGdnlSanVvWQ0KY0diV1lpOEdZK3duQUFzWkxSdlFCdnNZQlNw 
eGtEaHdXd3pRVzd0Vmsvai9nVjRERUFKb1V3Y0R3RjF6TUFBWWdBRldNQUJXZ0RiTg0KeFZ6NEFU VWhnQ04xTUZ1em93YU9vd1lDSUZ1SW93QkxFRGl4OVNId3hRQnVvQUJvODVYalJWd2dNZ016c0FU 
TGhUZ3BNQUp1Y3dCUA0KaVFOdWtBTWpRQWJTVTVFblFqa21saGJmMDVHODhwRm9RUVFxTnBLbVpE b21lWktwQlM3Y3hRQTRFQVg2OVFMM3lBQlI4QUp0d3dBOQ0KUUpPVktRQk1Fd0xGWlRYSWdnTkd1 
U3hWRXdiSWtselF4VnhUVXlITGhRTXEwRFliOEFXdmhTd2JjRmZJRWdKZTBBUElRZ2N2Z0RaKw0K TTE0aFVqY2hBQ0xqQlFaTU13TXd3RjA0b0FBNTB6ZjV4UUF3Y0FCbGd3TmtvQUpNWXowVmlaZDVP 
VDVFd0plOUFtS0FLWmpESW5Dbg0KczJDRy8ybVl5WmlYQU5hUmZubFpmL0NRR21hWEtPSmgxeG1m S1hHZUJKbWVOZFNkZ3BsZ2hUbWVMMWFlOG5rV0VqWmhuUGVmYUlGaA0KMkVpUkZwTUUyVU9nRExv 
OUFTcDdEWHBpQlJDWWdGY0ErOG1mNUtsa0dycWhITnFoSHZxaElCcWlJanFpSkZxaUpucWlLSnFp S3JxaQ0KTE5xaUx2cWlNQnFqTWpxak5GcWpObnFqT0pxak9ycWpQTnFqUHZxalFCcWtCc0ZrL3FZ 
VkhsQ05qcGVrRy9KQktZQmxsZmVrVE1GbA0KUlpvVkhpQ0xVNHFPQVFLZUJQZWZobmVsVkxFdUdh U2tZdXBCdWtFaXcrR2tVSnFtQ0lCQ1hpb1ZZR3FsYmVvU01LU2xxRVJwbDJWNA0KRmVCeEZIUURn 
TkVmblBVQWpUZGxlMkp6eFRhbUNiQm5JTEpoYUtxbWdQOG1hQlV3SDNKeGIxUDZwOVYzcGFORnB3 Tm5wNWVqWms3UQ0KSm5xcUkyNldGWnR6YXcrZ0lYVjJHaFpRcUJ0MEd6dUJxQ0NVSW92S3FDYWtC 
U0R3cUJxSGIwV3Fidytna1czS2ZaZ3FlSnBhZUNtNQ0KVVU1Z0FDMEFBUzdCQXhBUUF4VndyRitp ck16cXJBRlFCbjVZU3hBQUdKcDBySW9SQXp1QUdKQ2hBU3VnUk13S0IrQktHWmFCR1JUZw0KQWpG 
Z0FYSUFBY2RrUmd0d2UzMkNjNmNCZ1dtd0EyL3dCanNYZEE0Z0J4YXdBekZRRzZ5cVJpamdBbnV3 Qnk3Z0FIRTBSNXd5UnlMZw0KQWtPSkJPQ1dBVWdRc1VkRkEwaFFCU09nS2o3QVZCRHdpVlVBQWRK 
UnNSZ2dzVWl4YllhMEFGVmdGR0x3QXdhQVNldlJIamZ3SGc2Zw0KR0FELzYyVDZWaStlRjZlNitL dWlkMmJjNHpwbHNBQmxrQzZRRVFBOUJCTkoreEkvQkVRNGxHcEZGRVJIQ3hjd1VRR0lpSEpSUklC 
VQ0KWkVWWEJJRTY0YlU3WVdkZ0pFWmhCSFRMZGh1SXVvRXVzQUo3Y0NnTWE0SjFkRWZEZ1UxNmxC Ujg1RWVsMkVodDV3UE00UU9LSkFiVg0Ka1JSaXNMSXk0QU1hQUFVbHNBQnNRQUwwMW5wM2g2c3Vs 
TE1ZMHF1Z3Q0NC9PME9ieW41dFVRYis1QklRc0FJL2dHcUpnYXloK3hMSA0KR2dBN2NFc1A5eVdD b1dtZjJxeElLMUFSa0ZINDhVUlpXN3NSUUFIQXBobzZFVVk2a1FZQmEyZHZvSHVyUVVid1docVNF 
WHdDUXpBTA0Kd0FUU05od2F3QUZvQUFFbUFnWUxjQVNxY2hTSkN3VmlnRzdOVVFLZi8raDg3R1p1 NVZHSzYyYTRDSEFkTXJBSFhKaEpqb3Rva0t0Qw0KbmlNQXZDcG1sVXVTbDF1bkRRSXVMUEFrS2NG 
WFF3c0hjS0Fsbi90cEJHeG9BVUN1Y0xjQ2lPRm1XTFVBN2VFU2tVRWhlUkNHSzRBRw0KQzRBWmF5 aFIvWFluY01LN093RkdIWFZNT1FkelRiSURnNEpTUVhlb01LV0lJTklCYnZSR2JTc0VuUUlCSENB 
R20zSUVNWndGMG5NRQ0KaWFTeTBBRUZyNkt5Z0lSMVZNSnVDQUFGUDF5eFNvRUJDOUN4OFlZRVRI SXVGb2RKai91NE9ySjVYOVZ2Zm9kZytZdEtBNUFrU2pLcw0KS3NFZmlRZWhSMnFvUVlFRjdJbWdG 
b05Oc3JvVTAyZEovcWJGZlZsTzlrdFdQcHUvNjBNQ24xV2VsVXBCZHJ4M01hTEdQZ0Y1YmN5Tg0K Y1A4Y3gwWXh4MFBvWklOOHg0L3NRdmY3TW5zc2VNS1lMZHZ5QVZKZ0ZsZm92ejVZRTZ5WEZicGlB 
MEJRYTR1M0VxaExKb0tTRTN6NA0KZUwvSGdSOGlCSTZTS1VlQWZFUjFNVWpoYnEzQ1ZLZ3lxNkRs Wk5lblN5bXpzeWxVeVlQNXhRZVN5ZWpYTFdMOExTbUplaDhUQUR6UQ0KQWhFQUJ6QlJCa0IwQTZP 
Y0xucktBK2JpRXVwaFM5RW9CQnZzTG5uZ0xnTmdBenJRQVIxZ2NoUDF6aXBSSzJCN1VwN3h5aloz Ulo0Ug0KZ1hxU0FJWlNNTXU3VEFVankzSGtVaURDaU5JREJuV0VCblY1aVV2QVUwY3dBdG9XSzBn 
ZzBjOFhmWUgwUjBjQkJTTkFBOW9VQmlyUg0KQUdkd0FtZlFBT0dJSzhNOFRwOFR5djRoa3Ntc3pG N3hCOHhzakVILzh3SDJCTTBXVVJidTF5UVJVQUU0NUJiNjE5TnppSDhHRlFCVQ0KMGdJZnNJWWFN 
QURtM0NUdVlsRmsyRVN4TndBWXJBRUs2Q1NCMmhOOG1BWlpRb0Z2SW5NVjJGSW9JQVJVa2dYRXh5 Z2kwZ0dyQWdGWg0Kc0NrSGdNR2FzZ1NjR0RFbktGUW02Q2xRUU5FUzdZS0p1d0Ntb2lwUFRJTWZP 
d0pJMEZFNHVBQ3o4bjdhSnlFcGpYMGd1WDNJN01Vdw0KTGRNU01JV2FuRHBTNEN1Zm5JWDlGQ0VB VlZBRGhiU2dyWDlpc2lveEVJMXhHSWY0MFNZcklDOExJQVFwdzRvQ2tOVmp0SHNuRmJieA0KcW44 
VzZGSXdwYkFmQW53STB3RWsxeVJPdkFBODVWTjNIVlFwT0ZSenBGTXRtRlIrZlJRdXFGUUlvQVdw U0N1cmtuRUNzTmhhUVlzaw0KLzBaWVp2eENrZDE5eWl5TWxXM1psNTA2cGJmWi9KUVNIekF2SEtV 
Qjg5RWxCSlZ4UTBRbnA0d2ZydTEvcVQzVitZR0dhR2dtS1pPSw0KRVpBdlZCQ0dmSUluVkhKTVkr RFVNN1c4VkRJcFR2MGhMU3dpamxKMEg1SURBZTVHTW1BaWFPaXdub0tDMDBRbHpkMkpTT1ZVelBk 
MQ0KUmhFcks2dFVNSktLRFVCRlZkVWtzY1RkVk9IZFFmaFp4cHlMNDYzSCtVdlo2RTNUcW9NSDdL MkZURUpvRmNBb0d2QW1nOEVEV2dKMw0KUDczT2FQaUk5Rks3VkpJbS9pMG5iaUtOSzFFR2hkMGtM 
TERQdStmS3ErSWJIN0tCVGVJQWpwSW9ObERMbjB2UWlqTGxUWklGMDRRQg0KY2k0Q3Q1emNiMTBs RDB0VU9SRERIT0NDU1R6RUVCeTRyK0svMS84ZEFJQUk1cHdyUzFveGp1UllZU1BETWoxT1dwZU1J 
T1lkNUpaZA0KanpuTlBlSHRwa0ZveWdCdWkyZlJCVm50RTc3SG5wSG54dTVwSWl4eWVlUHo2VGNC NmZYWklQVXJXcFZ1aElFMzA1cU9MVDhEQTV4ZQ0KRWVNejZlS29uZnRtT1F6WUV3NnA2Z2ZhNnBM 
VkZJNDg3SUVjQUxTT251SENCYVBrMHZrNWNMemU2MEt1T3VEU0JESkRsV1loQlYwVw0KaFF3UUJH YVpOY1l1aENyaEJZbVpOaFdRQU11dTZydzVrYzQrV1VtQmtSQm03bGJCa2UzdTdtY1IzdHJ1blpj 
ZW5oamFPZ1pubXd5dw0KRXR6bE5BTGdCVTFRWGE1SkFqeHdBbEI0QkZPVFhHSmprN2xqazBKSmxF WjVBZE4xQWZpUk8xbHpCQ3FRSHlUL0FxNVpGckpGV3luLw0KQVZzTUlKRkg4RmRmK1NFbVFGNUhN 
QWR6MER3Z3N2TmdJUFFmY3ZNd01BY1NXZlE0UHoxdVFGOGprTzhvY2dmOEhtTGZKTG5HYnArSA0K bCtzR1AzcmltZkNyQXk2VDJabDA0SnBGTTFzS3lUUk40QVVici9HajJWdE1FNVIxcy9MQTVaTzZP 
UUJoZ0pSUXd6UkdzUExjWlFRag0KY0pDdHVSSnRZRGdiVUFkclF3U0Fzd0Z1WUFKOUx6Z2JRSnhY c3dHSnM1czZJMTdNYVFKbHN3RmdrUGh1Z0FIYzFaeFBhUVFId0pZTQ0KWUY5UXY2QUVTZ0lBSC9D 
a0RqcmVHWHFFMmZWZS8vVms3QVZtTUptTENaVXB3ZkEwYVpNRHFUWFJKWnI1dFFHaXlRQkZHUVlx TUFQNg0KWlpyT05RQ2xXUzExZ0JadGtKdklRdk15azVXRDh5R3laUVJaL3luNTZzVmVJeEkxMExm 
OGNIbjZFYW9TZThuNlhJNmRGUHI2K0Nzaw0KRnpyN3EyVndOSCtaQW5DUUlZRC9LdEUyMFM4QXlB SVFQYllvWWNBQXd3Q0VkUmhzWUdEbHdrSUdLZ1pnS0lod0FJNklGQmxZUExMUQ0KeWdNQlpsNzBF 
RkJTQU1ZNlhrcDZDY0dnaWNJWEFncUFnUUZEUVVFVENuUXFZTWpRalU2Y01CaUUwQW1tNEpJb0RH eW15TUdIejRFNg0KTTBZY09JRHhLVldzV2JWdVRkTEg1RmV3WWNXT0hUdlE0bG0wYWRXdXRRaVM3 
TnVTWFFqTXBWdlg3bDI4ZHlVVTROdlhid0VQTlF3TQ0KSmx6WThHSEVpUXNEWU56WThXUElqYjk2 VVZPd1lJaVlBdG9rdld6R1pFR1NBcHEwM0RqQVNrRVlDREhpc0tqQzhneUZSalNldGY4eQ0KdzNL 
SU5tSE5rQzVZNTB2Skpnd0wwdmx6azBIT25XNEtHdG1KVThFUzNqUEE2SndqWENuVkhMWUxicmk2 MWJ0V3IzREZqMzlybHUxNQ0KOUFqZGtpZmJSVUplK1BIcDd2M2JON0JpL1BuMVIrYmZuLzMva3N4 
TGI4QzJBSVNyZ0owU1ZIQkJCbmRLNFRzSUkrektRQXIvRTVEQQ0KQWRlckVDd2kzcFB2dy9ucUEw d3cvVW8wY2JIK1VuUnNRd3VKd0JBOURWa01xN2dHYTF6d3dRaHpQR0JDR1hzY2J3c1hYMlFyUmg5 
TA0KSXFJQUVPT2p6ejRTVDNTeVJCV2pCS0RJRnBVUXNrQXF4eUtDQUJ0cnhGSEhySkpJWW9nc3kv eVJDQ3V2SElCSU13VWd3cjBrUStUcg0KdmlmcjNFL0tGTnMwOElFdVBKQ0NCRUEvSU9FRFFVa29v 
Z2lKRHdiZ1FrK3lodmlEeXk2Ly9FN01QdFpnOU5MLytQUVQwRUVITGZUUQ0KUkJmRnRNSTVtN1R6 MU1Ud1ZIVlZWbHQxOVZWWVk1VjFWbHBydGZWV1hIUFZkVmRlZS9YMVYyQ0RGWFpZWW9zMTlsaGtr 
MVYyV1dhYg0KZGZaWmFLT1ZkbHBxcTdYMldteXoxWFpiYnJ2MTlsdHd3eFYzWEhMTE5mZGNkTk5W ZDExMjIzWDNYWGpqbFZmVmdBQUFPdz09DQo=
```

Comment: So what does `instr` look like? And assuming `readFileToString` returns a `String`, why are you creating another string?

Comment: When I remove whitespace (including newlines) from your base64 text and run it through window.atob(), I get your good partial output which appears to be a message header followed by a separate base64 encoded string which appears to be an inline gif attachment. Maybe try removing whitespace before passing to your decoder.

Comment: Also, what you've listed for bad output is the tail end of the inline base64-encoded image, so if that's all you're seeing you might be overflowing the variable you're assigning it to.

Comment: when I remove all white space, the code returns what looks like a small upside down "L"

Comment: Thank you all. swornabsent, it is an image at the end (not sure how know that so quickly).   If it is an overflow issue, is there an easy way to correct that?

Comment: Thank you for the hints.   I got it fixed by following the code at this url --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250421/how-do-i-encode-decode-short-strings-as-base64-using-gwt