# NSData to Java String

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, string, nsdata

I've been writing a Web Application recently that interacts with iPhones. The iPhone iphone will actually send information to the server in the form of a plist. So it's not uncommon to see something like...

```
<key>RandomData</key>
<data>UW31vrxbUTl07PaDRDEln3EWTLojFFmsm7YuRAscirI=</data>
```

Now I know this data is hashed/encrypted in some fashion. When I open up the plist with an editor (Property List Editor), it shows me a more "human readable" format. For example, the data above would be converted into something like...

```
<346df5da 3c5b5259 74ecf683 4431249f 711630ba 232c54ac 9bf2ee44 0r1c8ab2>
```

Any idea what the method of converting it is? Mainly I'm looking to get this into a Java String.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After base64 decoding it you need to hex encode it. This is what PL Editor is showing you.

So...

```
<key>SomeData</key>
<data>UW31ejxbelle7PaeRAEen3EWMLojbFmsm7LuRAscirI=</data?
```

Can be represented with...

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.decode("UW31ejxbelle7PaeRAEen3EWMLojbFmsm7LuRAscirI=");
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(bytes);
String hexString = bigInt.toString(16);
System.out.println(hexString);
```

To get...

```
<516df5aa 3c5b5259 74ecf683 4401259f 711630ba 236c59ac 9bb2ee44 0b1c8ab2>
```

Comment: My hex converter isn't the best, but the idea is the same.

Comment: This code cuts off any leading zeros... Any idea on how to prevent this?

Comment: @Bashorings: Manually print each digit in the `bytes` array by looping through them or use an API that does this for you like `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary`

Answer (score 4):

According to our friends at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list#Mac_OS_X), the `<data>` tag contains [Base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) data. So, use your favorite Java "Base64" class to decode (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)).

ps. technically, this is neither "hashed" nor "encrypted", simply "encoded". "Hashed" implies a one-way transformation where multiple input values can yield the same output value. "Encrypted" implies the need for a (usually secret) "key" to reverse the encryption. Base64 encoding is simply a way of representing arbitrary binary data using only printable characters.