# How to use base64 decoder in servlet

Tags: java, php, servlets, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode Base64 data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Hi,
     I have this php code which decodes the encoded bytearray in Base64 .I need to rewrite the code in servlet .I tried using some of the examples online but it didnt work .This is my php code[php code](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/03/09/android/android-upload-image-to-server/)

Please suggest me an equivalent servlet code...thank u ....i tried out this but its not working can u plase tell me where i am going wrong

```
String imgstring = request.getParameter("image");
    byte[] stringBytes = imgstring.getBytes();
    byte[] img = null;
    try {
        img = Base64.decode(stringBytes );
        response.setContentType ("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        String FILENAME="test.jpg";
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                FILENAME));
            os.write(img);

    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: Check out the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: There *is* a link to a Java Base64 class on the page you linked to.