# Converting byte array to base64 string java

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons

Trying to convert a `byte[]` to base64 string using 
`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`..For this my java code looks like:

```
 base64String = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(myByteArray);
```

But what i see is some invalid characters in the generated `base64` string..[image: ScreenShot]

Why do I see these `____` lines in my generated `base64` String?
Is it a valid string? 
Note the length of the generated string is dividable by four.

Comment: did you try decoding your output? Also, are you using the encoded base64 data in an URL. Use the URLSafe version only when the base64 encoding goes into a http/get or some other url-related operation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265912/javax-xml-binds-base64-encoder-decoder-eats-last-two-characters-of-string

Comment: Please provide the code you have written

Comment: @developer : All I use to convert the `byte[]` to string is a single methid which i have already provided in my question...

Answer (score 3):

have you tried with the `encodeBase64String` method instead of using `encodeBase64URLSafeString` ?

encodeBase64URLSafeString:

> Encodes binary data using a URL-safe variation of the base64 algorithm
>   but does not chunk the output. The url-safe variation emits - and _
>   instead of + and / characters.

encodeBase64String:

> Encodes binary data using the base64 algorithm but does not chunk the
>   output. NOTE: We changed the behaviour of this method from multi-line
>   chunking (commons-codec-1.4) to single-line non-chunking
>   (commons-codec-1.5).

source : [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
String sCert = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(pk);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful

```
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
encoder.encode(byteArray);
```

Comment: This is bad advice---`sun.misc` package hierarchy is not for public use.

Comment: I dont want to go with `sun.misc`

Answer (score 0):

you've got (at least) two flavours of base64, the original one using '+' and '/' in addition to alphanumeric characters, and the "url safe" one, using "-" and "_" so that the content can be enclosed in a URL (or used as a filename, btw).

It looks like you're using a base64 encoder that has been turned into "url-safe mode".

[apache's javadoc for URLSafeString()](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Oh, and `'_'` being the last character of the base64 alphabet, seeing strings of `"____"` means you've been encoding chunks of 0xffffff ... , just like seeing "AAAAAA" means there's a lot of consecutive zeroes.

If you want to be convinced that it's a normal case, just pick your favourite hexadecimal dumper/editor and check what your binary input looked like.

Comment: Looks a valid comment amongst all yes I have got `/` and replcaed the econding method with `encodeBase64URLSafeString` to avoid slashes.. Then it all started with `_`.. All i need to know is the above is a valid base64 string ?Kindly suggest.

Comment: you're asking if the string matches [0-9A-Za-z_-]+ or [0-9A-Za-z/+]+ ? that sounds like a job for a regexp.

Answer (score -1):

By the below process you can convert byte array to Base64

```
 // Convert a byte array to base64 string
    byte[] bytearray= new byte[]{0x12, 0x23};
    String s = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytearray);

    // Convert base64 string to a byte array
    bytearray = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(s);
```

***Edit:***

Please check for guide below link [commons apache](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/index.html)

Comment: ` sun.misc.BASE64Decoder()` ?? Why am trying with apache commons

Comment: sun.misc is something internal to Sun's implementation of java/javax packages. There is no guarantee it will always be there (esp. on a different JVM) nor that its interface will remain the same across different releases of the JVM, afaik.