# Base64 decoding returning junk

Tags: java, string, base64, httprequest

I am trying to decode a Base64 string from my authentication headers in Java. I am certain that the request being sent has a valid Base64 encoded string in the authentication header. Here is my decoding code:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
byte[] test = new Base64().decode(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
```

Before I decode the request it looks like this `Basic dXNlcjpmZGdmcw==`

After I try to decode it it looks like this: `«"qÕÍ•Èé™‘™Ì`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, and no matter what decode utility I use it always ends up looking like gibberish. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Make sure the string you pass to decode() starts with dXNl..., not Basic. FYI, the string in your question says: "user:fdgfs".

Comment: http://base64decode.org/ decodes it as user:fdgfs so it's possibly the byte array to string conversion that's screwing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder decoder = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder();
System.out.println(new String(decoder.decodeBuffer("dXNlcjpmZGdmcw==")));
```

Prints `user:fdgfs`. Note: [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) for better solutions. Have you checked what is returned by:

```
request.getHeader("Authorization")
```

?

Comment: I was an idiot and didn't remove the Basic from my string before decoding it, so it was attempting to decode "Basic dXNlcjpmZGdmcw==" instead of "dXNlcjpmZGdmcw=="

Comment: Do not use undocumented sun.* libraries in your code.  It may not be there next version or a different JVM implementation, and it may change it interface or specification without notice.  Remember, if it's a private library I can refactor it to my hearts content as long as I change my ***private*** dependencies on it.

Comment: @Software Monkey: you are absolutely right, that's why I pointed out link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) question *"for better solutions"*. I actually copied the first answer just to check the supplied Base64.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are trying to decode whole String "Basic dXNlcjpmZGdmcw==" instead of 
"dXNlcjpmZGdmcw==".