# Unable to get Proxy working with Socket

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I am trying to get Proxy working with Socket. But everytime I tried, it would returned a "**Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Proxy**" exception error

*at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:131)*

But if its Proxy.Type.SOCKS, it works.

```
public void Test()
{
   Socket s = null;
   SocketAddress addr = null;
   Proxy proxy = null;

   addr = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080);
   proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);
   socket = new Socket(proxy); // This is the line that is triggering the exception
}
```

Comment: You are using localhost(127.0.0.1 port 8080) as proxy, are you running a proxy server in local?

Comment: replace InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8080) with your proxy server ip  and port no.

Comment: Take a look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225873/how-to-connect-a-socket-server-via-http-proxy

Comment: @rao_555
Yes, I have a proxy server (Fiddler2) running under localhost.

I am also guessing that new Socket(Proxy p) constructor does not allow HTTP proxies to be used, only SOCKS. I have taken a look at Socket.java and if you used a Type.HTTP, it will throw an IllegalArgumentException right away.

Comment: So was this ever solved for you?

Comment: @David did you manage to find some solution?

Comment: No, and I don't recall the context of my issue at the time. But from the other answer, using newer Java version may fix the issue? The OP never mentioned what Java they were using.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly this is a bug in (Oracle) Java - only DIRECT and SOCKS proxy is supported for Socket. See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6370908.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me some ours of potentially frustrating debugging. Why the hell isn't this fixed.

Comment: Is this still not fixed? The bug ID shows resolved fixed back in 2013. Dependent on platform or Java version?

Comment: Looks like this should be fixed in some JDK 8 b82, and JDK 11+ should have this fixed?