# encode and decode base64 string to decimal string coddec

Tags: java, encoding, base64, decoding

I have a base64 string like this = "pCZXOVjpnlePyDk6znZrSw==" i need a encoder/decoder to convert it to decimal string like this = "84587163248712923874"
Is there any codec that do it?

Comment: Language, platform, context? It's also unclear what digits those are meant to be... please give more information.

Comment: encode/decode base64 to a string that contain only digits. java

Comment: That base 64 string decodes to the 16 bytes A426573958E99E578FC8393ACE766B4B whats their relationship to the number?

Comment: base64 is base64.  However, the encoder works only on bytes, so you must convert your characters to bytes before encoding, and convert back after decoding.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java tells you how to decode a base64 string, as for what you get back; if its an encoded decimal string that's what you will get, if its a picture of a cat, then you'll get that.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a two stage process:

1. Convert the Base64 string to a byte array.
2. Convert the byte array to a number.

16 bytes is too big for a Java long so I assume that you will need a `BigInteger`.  There is a `BigInteger` constructor that takes a byte array as parameter, though you will need to be careful with the sign bit.  The `toString()` method for the `BigInteger` will give you the string you want.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 encode/decode is part of the default libraries now (finally).  Look at the class **javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter**.  In there you will find two methods **printBase64Binary** and **parseBase64Binary** (along with a few other conversion routines).

Comment: This tells how to parse base64, but not how to convert the result (a byte array) to a decimal string.