# Base64 decoding issue on Java server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, base64

I am working on the client side and I am facing problems in encoding/decoding data. The decoded string received at server is different from the string sent by the client. I can't figure out what might be the problem. Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there something wrong at server or have I done something wrong?

I checked the result for for some string "abc" at my own end and I am getting the correct result. But when server does the decoding, it shows different result.

For Base64 I used [this](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/).

Answer (score 0):

Nitish i think now the fault you doing is in the sending it to server if both approach are using on client and server end then it will be a fault in the http message sending to server cross check that thing i think you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

How are you decoding on server side. which APIs are you using ?
You may want to look to [Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/). Also you can look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) for base64 encode/decode in java