# About base64 encoding and decoding in multiple language

Tags: java, javascript, encoding

Can we apply base 64 encoding in java and decode to get the same string using javascript ?

I need to do this to include three separate xml file in a single xml file, three of them being base64 encoded.

Comment: Sure, Base64 is widely supported everywhere, and it not at all difficult to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use Base 64 encoding in multiple languages. See [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Comment: if we encode the string "abcd" using java and send it to javascript, will the javascript get back the same string after decoding it ?

Comment: Yes. Base64 is implemented the same way. Encoding strings in Base64 makes no sense. Base64 is meant to encode binary data (e.g images) as text.

Comment: True, however there's a case for encoding a string. eg if you are using json in your applications but you need to process external messages that are using a different format.