# Use Java Serialization to Save Object

Tags: java, serialization

I'm planning to use Serialization to save the Bean modified by user--to store the history record. But the ByteArrayOutputStream output a byte array:byte[]. If I convert it to String and convert it back, then it can't be de-serialized. --How to explain this?
  If I use byte array to store in the oracle, it's complicated.Is there any way to make the String can be de-serialized? Thank you!
  I'm a Chinese, so forgive me for my bad English. :)

Comment: Do you have a short code snippet that shows your approach? I'm pretty sure that character encoding is the issue here.

Comment: Serializing to String doesn't work (decently) simply because Strings are not byte[]; you could use base64 encoding to to save bytes to a String. The problem though is that persistence through byte[] is not a good idea to begin with, it is susceptible to many problems; you should either use an ORM, save the fields by inspecting the bean or use better serialization, like by JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize and `ObjectInputStream` to deserialize objects. The API documentation of those classes has examples that show how to use them to serialize and deserialize objects to and from a file.

Don't try to force a `byte[]` into a `String`. (Why would you want to put it in a `String`?). Serialized objects are binary data, not text characters that you would store in a `String`.

Comment: Thank you for helping! The project need to store the object in DB, so I'm trying to use else ways like JSON. Thanks again!

Comment: If you need to store objects in JSON format then the Java serialization mechanism is not what you want to use. Use a library such as [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: I'm prepare to use GSON in project, your advise is useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In byte[] all possible byte values can be used i.e. -128 to 127.  However, in text these values and combination of values can be invalid and not convert to text as expected.

I suggest you consider a text based serialization like XML or JSon.  These can be read/written as text safely.  Text base serialization can be read by a human and possibly edited as text if you want to correct a value.

---

EDIT: I would look at using [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) which is crude, but built in or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for XML and JSon, which is more flexible and efficient (but requires a couple of extra libraries)

Comment: Your advise is great.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Brief Answer: encode the byte array as a Base64 string.

Base64 is a way of ensuring that binary data can be stored and transmitted as text - a reasonable explanation can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64); if you don't encode the byte array, data can easily become "corrupted" by the use of different codepages etc. One thing to be aware of - base64 encoding will take more space than the byte array (so a byte array of 20 bytes may take around 30 characters to be  stored)

There are many libraries that can encode/decode Base64 [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) is just one. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) for more discussions on which library to use (there is a "private" one in the JDK, but use of it may be considered questionable by some developers).

So, in summary, to serialize an object into string, us an `ObjectOutputStream` and a `ByeArrayOutputStream` to convert to a byte array, and then use a Base64 encoder to translate that into a string.

To deserialize, use a Base64 decoder to convert the string back into a byte array, and then use a `ByteArrayInputStream` and a `ObjectInputStream` to read it back.

Comment: Thanks but I'm going to use Gson to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static final String SQL_SERIALIZE_OBJECT="insert into serialized_java_objects(serialized_id,object_name,serialized_object) values (ser_id_seq.nextval,?,?)";

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(objectToBeSerilize);
        byte[] serializeBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_SERIALIZE_OBJECT);
        prepStatement.setString(1, objectToBeSerilize.getClass().getName());
        prepStatement.setBytes(2, serializeBytes);


        prepStatement.executeUpdate();
```