# Base64 string representation of MongoDB ObjectId in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

Using the Java driver, what's the best way to convert an ObjectID to/from a string with Base64 encoding?

The ObjectIds will be part of a URL so I'd like to shorten them a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ObjectId class does have a toString() method, and a string may be provided in the constructor.  However, these strings are base-16 (hexadecimal), and may bot be what you are looking for.

The API information may be found here:
http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/

For base 64 encoding, a colleague of mine suggested that it may be preferable to use the toByteArray() method, and convert that to a base 64 string.  Going the other way, the ObjectId constructor may be passed a byte array.

A Google search for "java library base64 encoding" reveals another Stack Overflow question that contains more detail on converting byte arrays to base 64 strings and back again.
[Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

The above thread contains a link to the base64 class, part of the Apache Commons Codec.
http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Hopefully this will get you where you need to go, or at least give you some additional options to consider.

Comment: Thanks, Marc!  Looks like we ended up cross posting answers.  I dug around and came up with the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the ObjectId source code and none of the internal string-ifying methods help.

Seems that you need to use`ObjectId.toByteArray()` and `ObjectId( byte[])` in conjunction with an external Base64 encoder/decoder.  The Java Mongo driver used to have `com.mongodb.util.Base64`, but it doesn't seem to be part of the library any longer so I used the [Base64 library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) in Apache Commons.

Here's an example of the conversions using Base64 in Apache Commons:

```
static public ObjectId toObjectId( String stringId)
{
    return new ObjectId( Base64.decodeBase64( stringId));
}

static public String toString( ObjectId objectId)
{
    return Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString( objectId.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Base64, you could just use [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html), which has nothing to do with MongoDB but converts Strings into a valid URL-Strings.

Comment: Thanks, Nico, but that's not quite what I'm looking for.  Mongo's ObjectID's are internally 12 bytes of binary data that the ObjectId can externally represent as a hex string.  I'm looking for a convenient / efficient way to represent the object as a base64 string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter which is a part of Java

parseBase64Binary(String lexicalXSDBase64Binary) to convert a base64 into a binary string
printHexBinary(byte[] val) to print it out as a hex string.

The advantage of this is you are not adding any additional libraries outside JavaEE5 or Java 6