# add image to Eclipse runnable jar + insert it into HTML file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to insert an image into a HTML file from a java method with Eclipse.
When I export the project into a Runnable jar, the image doesn't appear.

I searched a lot on the internet, and i did a ressource folder, but it doesn't work.

src
--test4
----IHM2.java
----test4.java
--res
----logo2.png

```
public class IHM2
{
private File htmlFile;
private FileWriter fw;
private BufferedWriter writer;

public IHM2() throws IOException {
    htmlFile = new File("IHM2.html");
    fw = new FileWriter("IHM2.html");
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);
}

public void HTML_opening() throws IOException
{

    writer.write("<html>");
    writer.write("<head>");
    writer.write("</head>");
    writer.write("<body>");
    writer.write("  <img src='res/logo2.png'>");

}

public void HTML_closing() throws IOException
{
    writer.write("</body>");
    writer.write("</html>");
    writer.close();
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(htmlFile.toURI()); 
}
}
```

Any one please provide me an answer ?

**SOLUTION :**
I put `writer.write("   <img src='./logo2.png'>");`
Because I looked into the .jar file and logo2.png was out of the folder test4.

Comment: Were you able to add the image?

Comment: @Garry, your solution didn't work. But I thank you for telling me to look into the jar file, cause it did help ! --> I edited my post with the solution.

Comment: Great...well if it helped, consider up-voting an helpful answer.

Comment: @Garry i already tried to vote it helpful. However my account is new so ... i can't.

Comment: oops I didnt noticed you need 15 rep although, I was also suggesting for all the answers on SO ;)  ... +1

Answer (score 0):

Check inside the jar, do you have `logo2.png`?

If not, while exporting the jar from eclipse as runable jar, use the radio button "package  required libraries into generated jar". If the res folder is a source folder then the png image will be copied into the root.

so instead of `res/logo2.png` you simply need to use `logo2.png`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the best way to port your html with your jar file is to convert it into base64 data.

You can get your base64 of your image from the following link:

http://beta.base64-image.de/

Follow the instruction and get your image code. Once you uploaded your image, get the code and use it in your src="" tag.

Or else if you want to show the html, you must have the image next to it.

For more information you can check: 
[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

You can also find ways to convert your image directly from java using:

[Java - Convert image to Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226046/java-convert-image-to-base64)

Finally,
if you are interested to use fines in your resources, in somewhere else than your jar, you must save them into your hard disk, so they will be accessible by other apps, and then you can address it to open with any program.

Check this:

[How to correctly get image from 'Resources' folder in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845231/how-to-correctly-get-image-from-resources-folder-in-netbeans)

Comment: thank you for sharing this interesting way of inserting an image in a HTML file. At work uploading picture is forbidden due to the proxy server. But it's a nice to know that ;-)

Comment: You can use Java's. I use it and I don't like uploading myself as well.