# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2, jsonSyntax Error

Tags: java, android, json, hashset

I want to save `Hashset` Object in to `Sharedpreference` and than want retrieve that data. I am storing data in to `hashset` and and converting object in to `json` using `Gson`. Actually m storing bitmap in to `Hashset`. I am able to convert and save `Hashsetobject`  into  `sharedpreference`. I am getting problem when I am retrieving and converting `json` to `Hashset` Object.

```
HashSet<images> img = new HashSet<images>(CIRCLES_LIMIT);
```

Here is Method For Saving `Object` in to `Sharedpreference`.

```
  public void saveString() throws JSONException {

    Object spSquare = c.getStringDrawObjImages();


    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();


    String jsonSquare = gson.toJson(spSquare)
    editor.putString("kEySquare", jsonSquare);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Method For Retrieving That Object.

```
   public void openString() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String jsonSquare=sharedPrefs.getString("kEySquare",null);



  Type typeSquare = new TypeToken<HashSet<images>>(){}.getType();
    HashSet<images> arrayListSquare = gson.fromJson(jsonSquare,typeSquare);`//getting Exception here jsonSyntax Error`


    if (arrayListSquare != null) {
        img = arrayListSquare;
    }
}
```

Comment: share your json

Comment: {
 "img": "[Circle[218.69626, 475.58936, 0,android.graphics.Bitmap@42e13c70,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,], Circle[186.74065, 670.43713, 0,android.graphics.Bitmap@42e13c70,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,]]"
}

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment your `json` as follows is not in format so that `Gson` can parse it as you are receiving your circle attribute in `string` not as `json`.

```
{
  "img": "[Circle[218.69626, 475.58936, 0,android.graphics.Bitmap@42e13c70,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,]‌​, Circle[186.74065, 670.43713, 0,android.graphics.Bitmap@42e13c70,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,]‌​]"
}
```

So your `Json` is received as object having only attribute that is `img`.

and you are parsing it as array. That's error. So contact your back end developer and change `json` structure accordingly.

Comment: Actually I have checked json in jsonlint.com and it showing valid json

Comment: @NitinMakwana It is valid json but not valid for parsing as array Via Gson

Comment: Is it possible to convert bitmap in to json?

Comment: @NitinMakwana You need to convert your image to Base64 String and then you can send it via json as String. But again on sever you need to change Base64 string to image.

Comment: can you please  provide some hint how can i do that with my hashset object of bitmaps?

Comment: @NitinMakwana refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10226133/1157879). But if there are log of images then I recomemend set url's of those images in json

Answer (score 1):

You serialise a object and want to deserialise it into a HashSet. That's the problem.

```
Object spSquare = c.getStringDrawObjImages();
```

What's the type of spSquare? Suppose it is 'Foo.class', you should deserialise it like this:

```
Foo foo = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Foo.class);
```

'foo.img' should be your HashSet

Comment: You should find out the right class. What on earth is the type of spSquare ? It seems to have only one field in it which is 'img', and the field 'img' turn out to be your HashSet, isn't it?