# Upload image, encode to base64 Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, base64

I have a question.
I'm working on a Spring web MVC project where I need to upload
an image, convert it to base64 and then write it to a mysql database. 
I'm very new to spring and I've searched the web finding a lot of tutorials that just don't really fit my answer.
I basically don't know where to start..do I use javascript to do this in the jsp file? Or is it better to use java? I literally have no idea where to start, it sounds difficult to me but I'm sure there is a very easy way to do this. I just have to get used to spring a little bit more. 
Can someone please point me in a direction about how to do this? 
Also, I'm using annotations and no xml.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create Spring controller and send image file as multipart request to that controller, then convert image to base64 in java.

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226046/java-convert-image-to-base64)

Comment: Thank you, I'm just a little bit unsure about where to do what. Do I encode to base64 in the controller? And in what file do I send it to the database?

Comment: first use multipart to get file in controller [learn from this] (https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)

Comment: In controller you will get byte from multipart object and convert it into base64 string and store this string into database.