# How to upload PDF file to server using PHP in Android?

Tags: php, android, pdf, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to upload PDF files to a server using PHP in Android. For that I get the URI of the selected file and POST those data to a PHP file in my server. This is where I post that data:

```
URL url = new URL(url_path);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
InputStream inputStream = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
Log.e("URI",path.toString());
int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
Log.e("URI",String.valueOf(bytesAvailable));
outputStream.flush();
inputStream.close();
```

This data is posted to this php file:

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
$file_name = date("U").".pdf";
$server_path = "uploads/";
$web_path = "http://mysite/uploads/";

$file = $server_path.$file_name;
file_put_contents($file,"");

$fp = fopen("php://input",'r');
echo 'fp : '.$fp;
while ($buffer = fread($fp,8192)){
    echo $buffer;
    file_put_contents($file,$buffer,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}?>
```

For each upload, it creates a new file in my uploads directory. But the size of the PDF is 0 bytes. I have no idea why. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change file to base64 and send like text to php file.

Comment: @Breakermind Can you please give me a link toan example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226046/java-convert-image-to-base64

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/base64-encoding-java-8

Comment: example android app https://github.com/fxstar/AndroidAppExample

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

---

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams 
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}
```

---

Ref: http://www.coderefer.com/android-upload-file-to-server/
and https://github.com/vamsitallapudi/AndroidUploadFileToServer

Comment: It fails here, `!selectedFile.isFile()`. I get the path from onactivityresult of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Why the Uri fails here?

Comment: I would recommend you to use retrofit to upload a file.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing it yourself, you could easily use this library called ION: https://github.com/koush/ion . Uploading a pdf file is as simply as:

```
Ion.with(getContext())
.load("your url")
.setMultipartFile("archive", "application/pdf", new File("path to file"))
.setCallback(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use Retrofit instead. Here is a sample app you can use: https://github.com/hidrodixtion/Example-Retrofit-Image-Upload

Comment: I'll try with Retrofit. Thanks a lot.