# How to encode xml to Base64 and send back as servlet response?

Tags: servlets, groovy, base64

I wrote a servlet (with .groovy extension) which should return xml in Base64 encoding

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String fileName=(String) request.getParameter("fileName")

    if (fileName == null || fileName.equals(""))throw new ServletException("Invalid or non-existent file parameter in SendXml servlet.")
    if (fileName.indexOf(".xml") == -1)fileName = fileName + ".xml"

    System.out.println(fileName)

    try {

      String relativeWebPath = "/WEB-INF/classes/com/abc/csm/xml/"+fileName
      String absoluteDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeWebPath)

      String fileContents=new File(absoluteDiskPath).text
      response.setContentType("text/xml")
      response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment filename="+ fileName)

      XmlHandler xm=new XmlHandler()

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()
      String enxml=xm.encodeBase64(fileContents)
      response.setContentLength((int) enxml.length)

      out.println(enxml)
      out.close()
      out.flush()
    } catch (Exception e) {       println e     } 
}
```

XmlHandler encodeBase64 method

```
def encodeBase64(String text) {
    return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(text.getBytes()))
}
```

But I guess something is missing. Please help

**Update**

Also please comment is it proper way to access files from package?

Comment: @Teg: on the console the file name is printed and then `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Which line does it say throws the NPE?

Comment: @tim_yates: XmlHandler was giving prob, so I put the encodeBase64 in servlet itself, now it gives `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Base64 for class: com.abc.csm.version.GetResponse`

Comment: Posted an answer on the Groovy way of doing encoding to Base64

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace:

```
  String enxml=xm.encodeBase64(fileContents)
```

with

```
  String enxml = fileContents.bytes.encodeBase64()
```

Or, better to pass an encoding to the call to `getBytes`:

```
  String enxml = fileContents.getBytes( 'UTF-8' ).encodeBase64()
```

Also, I believe you're missing a semicolon after `attachment` in your header...  The line should read:

```
  response.addHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=$fileName" )
```

---

#### Edit, and encoding and decoding example:

Encode:

```
String encoded = "tim_yates".getBytes( 'UTF-8' ).encodeBase64()
```

Decode:

```
String original = new String( encoded.decodeBase64(), 'UTF-8' )
assert original == 'tim_yates'
```

Comment: I get back the response, in fiddler I can see it but when I assign it to a variable and send it again to another redirection it has some other data appended to it. Is `response.setContentType("text/xml")` correct for this encoding?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Updated with decode example... If you are sending Base64 encoded data, then I believe you should do `response.addHeader( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'base64' )`.  Why not just send the plain XML without Base64 encoding though?

Comment: the original project sends it through encoding it, so I have to mimic the same thing with some extra features

Comment: I used your edited code, now when I receive and resend it to another servlet it gives me `java.lang.RuntimeException: bad character in base64 value` sorry for so much trouble

Comment: @AbhishekSimon no worries ;-) If you've set the content transfer encoding, the other end might be decoding it to xml automatically... Print it out before you decode it to check

Comment: Ok it prints the encoded xml (some garbage) I used [this](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/) to check the xml and it looks good. I am using `println xml
  root=new XmlParser().parseText(new String( xml.decodeBase64(), 'UTF-8' ))`

Comment: No it still gives `java.lang.RuntimeException: bad character in base64 value`

Comment: Ya in the online tool it decodes fine. The xml is more than 3 MB size if that helps

Comment: In my test groovy program it says `Groovy:String too long. The given string is 174996 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is 
  allowed.`

Comment: Try using a different decoding method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: @AbhishekSimon I suspect the problem you're getting with your test script is that by dumping the huge xml into the script, you're hitting JVM class file size limitations...

Comment: I used commons codec and it worked. thanks for all the help :)