# How to map a byte[] property with Hibernate?

Tags: java, string, hibernate, encoding, sha1

I'm using Hibernate/Java to persist an entity to a database. The entity has a *password* field which is a **String**. When registring a user in my application, I hash the password using SHA-1 (I acknowledge this is a little weak). This produces a **byte[]** which I then convert to **String** using
   `new String(byte[] arr);`
Whenever I want to log a user in, I simply retrieve the hashed password from the database (as **String**) and compare it with the digest of the input password at login using
   `hashedPasswordFromDatabase.equals(SHA1_HASH(inputPassword));`

**This worked perfectly** on my development system (Windows 7, JDK 1.6.0_23 / JDK 1.7, MySQL 5.5, Tomcat 6.0.26) but upon deploying it on our server (running JDK 1.6 on Linux), the *equals* method never evaluates to TRUE even for equal passwords. I quickly setup a new development system (Ubuntu 12.04, MySQL 5.5, JDK 1.7.0_03, Tomcat 7.0.22) and it doesn't work there too.

I'm aware of the possible encoding issues stated in the Java API documentation for the **String** class and also stated in several places here on SO. I've tried a couple of encodings suggested on this forum (e.g Base64, Latin-1) and I ended up with **UnsupportedEncodingException**. I think I'll be better off avoiding the String conversion. So how do I design my database such that the Hibernate-generated entity class comes up with **byte[]** for the *password* field instead of **String**?

Comment: +1, very good question.  As an aside that is not an answer to your question, I've had very good luck using some of the Commons Base64 utilities going into and out of the database.

Comment: Why would you store a string representing a number instead of storing the number itself?

Comment: Don't use one round of hashing to protect passwords. Use something like PBKDF2 or bcrypt with 10s of thousands of rounds---even 100k is not unreasonable. Storing a fixed-length `byte[]` directly should be easy for more database, but you can always create a `BigInteger` from a byte array and store that as a numeric type.

Comment: @erickson yeah good one there. I intend to upgrade the strength of the password protection (scraping out SHA-1, salting, multiple hashing, etc) after getting around this problem.

Comment: What is the data type in the database?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the problem is most likely in `byte[]` to `String` conversion. You must know that SHA produces raw `byte` array and there is no guarantee that arbitrary `byte[]` will produce valid `String`, irrespective to encoding. Thus your code was only working *by accident*.

Avoid the problem altogether by:

- storing raw `byte[]` in BLOB - the safest and most storage-effective way. In Hibernate just use `byte[]` property on your POJO.
- encode `byte[]` using [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) (check out [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695)) and store it as a string.

BTW [remember about salting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean BLOB will actually make Hibernate generate the field in the entity as `byte[]`?

Comment: @SayoStealth-virusOladeji: If you use `byte[]`, hbm2ddl should generate BLOB. And vice-versa - if you have a BLOB in your database, you can safely map it to `byte[]`.

Comment: Great! I'm currently going through the Base64 page you shared; its worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the bad database design push me to use a Blob in case of Clob. The solution was Map in hibernate the property with the Lob annotation and put another property in String type.

In other level of the code, when i call the get or set, i use the String property and this one, get or set the byte array value.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CMUN_TAGS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idSeqTag", sequenceName = "SEQ_CMUN_TAGS")
public class CmunTagsDO implements java.io.Serializable {
  private BigDecimal lngIdTag;
  private byte[] blobValTag;
  private String strValTag;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "LNG_ID_TAG", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 0)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idSeqTag")
  public BigDecimal getLngIdTag() {
    return this.lngIdTag;
  }

  public void setLngIdTag(BigDecimal lngIdTag) {
    this.lngIdTag = lngIdTag;
  }

  @Column(name = "BLOB_VAL_TAG", nullable = false)
  @Lob
  public byte[] getBlobValTag() {
    return this.blobValTag;
  }

  public void setBlobValTag(byte[] blobValTag) {
    this.blobValorTag = blobValorTag;
  }

  @Transient
  public String getStrValTag() {
    strValTag = new String(getBlobValTag());
    return strValTag;
  }

  public void setStrValTag(String strValTag) {
    setBlobValTag(strValTag.getBytes());
    this.strValTag = strValTag;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your byte to an hexadecimal representation like this:

```
public String encryptPassword(String passwordInClear) {
            // Salt all you want here.
            MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] digest = sha256.digest(passwordInClear.getBytes());
    return digestToString(digest);
}

private String digestToString(byte[] digest) {
    StringBuilder hashString = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(digest[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hashString.append('0');
            hashString.append(hex.charAt(hex.length() - 1));
        } else {
            hashString.append(hex.substring(hex.length() - 2));
        }
    }
    return hashString.toString();
}
```

Comment: How does this make affect the strength of the hashed password? Does this approach weaken it?

Comment: @SayoStealth-virusOladeji No, it does not weaken it or strengthen it. This is a simple thing that maps a byte onto its "equivalent" string value by representing each byte by its numeric value (0 becomes "00", 16 becomes "10", 255 becomes "FF", etc...). Passing from one to the other is bidirectional but the real "strength" or "weakness" is in your digesting of the password.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I think I'll employ this approach since I won't have to touch the database and any other thing close to it :)