# How to to use Base64.java file in my code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, base64, http-authentication

I am trying this

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpBasicAuth {

public static void downloadFileWithAuth(String urlStr, String user, String pass, String outFilePath) {
    try {
        // URL url = new URL ("http://ip:port/download_url");
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        String authStr = user + ":" + pass;
        String authEncoded = Base64.encodeBytes(authStr.getBytes());

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncoded);

        File file = new File(outFilePath);
        InputStream in = (InputStream) connection.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
            out.write(b);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

1. It works fine but gives an error " Cannot find symbol error Base64Encoder"
2. Downloaded the Base64.java file

Now I don't know how to use this file with my project to remove the error.
can you tell me please the how to use the Base64.java file to remove the error?

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Which library did you download Base64.java from? You should probably include the entire library rather than copying and compiling just Base64.java.

Comment: From here http://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/base64/2.3/ I have downloaded it.

currently I am not getting anything, I am new to java, so can you help me that what to do now?

Comment: Please take a look here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java). It'll point you to some commonly used Base64 libraries and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to import the `Base64` into your code. The import are depends on your source file. 
[Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has a solid implementation of Base64.

example:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: It gives class,interface or enum expected :-( . What to do now?

Comment: He's getting an error finding symbols for Base64Encoder. The Base64 class probably has other dependencies.

Comment: "class,interface or enum expected " is the full error message

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the Base64 encode/decode capability that is present in the JDK itself.  The package **javax.xml.bind** includes a class **DatatypeConverter** that provides methods to print/parse to various forms including

```
static byte[] parseBase64Binary(String lexicalXSDBase64Binary)
static String printBase64Binary(byte[] val)
```

Just import **javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter** and use the provided methods.