# How to use base64 to encrypt and decrypt?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert byte array to base64 format in java.
my problem is sun.misc.BASE64Decoder cannot be  used? Is there any alternative?

```
byte[] buf = new byte[] { 0x12, 0x23 };
String s = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(buf);
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code ? It does work...

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear. What does "Base64 does not support to my program" mean? What are you trying to do? Are you aware that base64 is just a way of representing binary data in text? (It's not encryption at all.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: See answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: My program is not supported this header files.

Comment: import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this library: [MigBase64](http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/)

Use it like this:

```
 byte [] buf = new byte[]{0x12, 0x23};
 String s = Base64.encode(buf);
```

Comment: you should download it from http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/ and add the jar to your classpath.

Comment: It's not a jar actually, it's just a source file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Base64 is not an encryption technique. It is just an encoding mechanism. If you're looking for enryption you're barking up the wrong tree.
2. `import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` is not a 'header file', it is an import statement. It may not compile if you are using a non-Sun/Oracle JDK. It may give you warnings which you should heed. As you haven't actually said what problem you are having it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: Thanks. I import this statement i got a error message is 'Access restriction: The type BASE64Decoder is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar'

Comment: @Jahir So (a) adjust your IDE not to treat that as an error, or (b) use another Base-64 encoder such as the Apache one.