# convert base64 String to Byte code in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode Base64 data in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

I am working on java profile, I want to know , how to convert the base64 string to byte array. could any one please provide code & it will be help fule to me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 14):

You can also use Apache Commons Codec (http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

```
String example = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="
byte[] decoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(example .getBytes());
```

Comment: Thank you buddy. The Java's stock parser was not working for me. This worked. :)

Comment: Since Java 8 you can use the built in `java.util.Base64`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;

BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageData);
```

Where `imageData` is String containing Base64 data.

Comment: Where is that BASE64Decoder from?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/469739/1793718

Comment: Your program becomes non-portable because sun.misc package is not part of Java SE API and is not guaranteed to be present in the standard library.