# Decoding a Base64 string in Java

Tags: java, base64

I'm trying to decode a simple Base64 string, but am unable to do so.  I'm currently using the `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` package.

The test string I'm using is: `abcdefg`, encoded using PHP `YWJjZGVmZw==`.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode("YWJjZGVmZw==");
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes) + "\n") ;
```

The above code does not throw an error, but instead doesn't output the decoded string as expected.

Comment: well, first of all, you should always specify a character set when converting from bytes to chars, perhaps "US-ASCII" for you example string (`new String(decodedBytes, "US-ASCII")`).

Comment: @jtahlborn the apache commons codec is built to "just work" in system default encoding if you don't specify otherwise

Comment: @TomasB code you posted works fine for me, is that the full sample?

Comment: The code you pasted works all right for me. Are you certain that that code snippet actually gets executed at all? Have you added some fixed string println or similar?

Comment: Your code works fine and prints "abcdefg".

Comment: @Affe - i have no idea what you mean by it "just working in the system default encoding".  regardless of the library used, when you convert bytes to chars, you should _always_ specify a charset.

Comment: I tried to add "UTF-8" no change.
@erickson - it print nothing :-(

Comment: show your entire example program

Comment: If it prints nothing, the problem is elsewhere in your program, not with the Base-64 decoding.

Comment: @TomasB Edited my anwser, this should work.

Answer (score 80):

Modify the package you're using:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

And then use it like this:

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64("YWJjZGVmZw==");
System.out.println(new String(decoded, "UTF-8") + "\n");
```

Comment: Be careful with sun.* packages! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: Sorry I should specified that I have to use org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 because it's a safe url decoder.

Comment: There's javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary in JDK so you don't need to use sun API or external libraries to work with base64.

Comment: @RTB you should always use a characted encoding when constructing a string from a byte[]. Change to e.g. `new String(decoded, "UTF-8")`

Comment: @TomasB If my anwser helped please accept it so others can learn form it. If not how can i help you further?

Comment: On Android org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 marked as deprecated. In this case use android.util.Base64 instead.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use apache, you can use Java8:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("YWJjZGVmZw=="); 
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes) + "\n");
```

Answer (score 17):

The following should work with the latest version of Apache common codec

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("YWJjZGVmZw==");
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes));
```

and for encoding

```
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(decodedBytes);
System.out.println(new String(encodedBytes));
```

Answer (score 3):

Commonly base64 it is used for images. if you like to decode an image (jpg in this example with org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 package):

```
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(imageJpgInBase64);
FileOutputStream fos = null;
fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\output\\image.jpg");
fos.write(decoded);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Base64 is a byte[] encoding specification and has nothing specifically to do with images nor is such a practice common.

Comment: Base 64 encoding of images is common on older or less sophisticated messaging protocols.

Comment: It's common enough to encode images in base64 when embedding them in XML documents or in HTML data URIs.