# How to decode base64 in java

Tags: java

I am getting a `base64encoded` xml data in webservice response and I want to decode it in Java . 
I tried `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`

```
byte bytesEncoded[] = base64encodedStringfromWebservice.getBytes();
// Decrypt data on other side, by processing encoded data
byte[] valueDecoded= Base64.decodeBase64(bytesEncoded );
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

but still some characters like (< , />) are not getting decoded properly .

Please suggest how to decode it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The `getBytes` method from `String` [is platform specific](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29). You need to specify an *encoding*, and later use that same encoding to decode the string. You can just use UTF8.

You also need to do the steps in reverse order: string -> base64 -> raw utf8 bytes -> base64 -> string

```
// ENCODE data
byte bytesEncoded[] = base64encodedStringfromWebservice.getBytes("UTF8");

// DECODE data on other side, by processing encoded data
String base64encodedStringfromWebservice = new String(bytesEncoded, "UTF8");
byte[] valueDecoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64encodedStringfromWebservice);
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifiying the charset you are using. for example, utf-8, and as you can see here: [Decoding a Base64 string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544568/decoding-a-base64-string-in-java)

```
byte[] valueDecoded= Base64.decodeBase64(bytesEncoded);
System.out.println("Decoded value is " + new String(valueDecoded, "UTF-8"));
```