# Converting BinHex file to normal file using Java

Tags: java, decoding

I have a binhex file. This file should be converted to normal readable file using java code.
I found a similar question here,

[Binhex decoding using java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467973/binhex-decoding-using-java-code)

But the answer is not working.

I tried Base64, the file is converted to some other format which is not human readable.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

The code i tried is as below

```
File f = new File("Sample.pdf");
Base64 base64 = new Base64();
byte[] b = base64.decode(getBytesFromFile(f));          
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Dcode.pdf");           
fos.write(b);
fos.close();

public static byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    long length = file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;
    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) 
    {
        offset += numRead;
    }
    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
    }
    is.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

The file Sample.pdf is BinHex ecoded. I want the file to be decoded.

Comment: What is your code? What is not working about your code? Stack Overflow might be cool and all, but it doesn't yet have a crystal ball.

Comment: I tried the base64 decoding as below.       Base64 base64 = new Base64();      byte[] b = base64.decode(getBytesFromFile(f));      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Dcode.pdf");        fos.write(b);     fos.close();

Comment: Add it to your question (as well as the exception/issue result).

Comment: As BinHex format has been in practical use in many places, I expect a number of BinHex-encoded resources around the web. As using the official BinHex software to decode such files requires access to a Mac as far as I understand things, that's not always an option, so being able to decode these things using Java makes sense. I'm a bit surprised that this question has been closed, and will **vote to reopen**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Difference to Base64

From what I find online, there are different versions of the [BinHex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binhex) format. None of them is exactly the same as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There are however major similarities. Taking for example the [BinHex 4.0 specs](http://files.stairways.com/other/binhex-40-specs-info.txt), we see that the major binary content is encoded using an encoding scheme with base 64, thus encoing 3 octets to 4 characters. It uses a different alphabet, though:

```
BinHex: !"#$%&'()*+,-012345689@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVXYZ[`abcdefhijklmpqr
Base64: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQERTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
```

So you'd either have to translate from one set of characters to the other, or do the decoding yourself.

Apart from the bulk of the binary content, there is some additional meta data included in the format. According to the spec, that includes delimiters between data and resource fork content, checksums, and some other bits of information.

## Implementation

The following code will decode a BinHex input file and write its data fork to an output file. It should be easy enough to adjust this code to your needs.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class BinHexDec {

    private Charset charset;

    private String filename;

    private int dbegin, dend, rbegin, rend;

    public BinHexDec(String... args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = System.in;
        OutputStream out = System.out;
        charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
        if (args.length >= 1)
            in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        if (args.length >= 2)
            out = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
        if (args.length >= 3)
            charset = Charset.forName(args[2]);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, charset);
        byte[] data;
        data = unbase(reader);
        reader.close();
        if (data.length < 27)
            throw new IOException("Too little data");
        data = unrle(data);
        parse(data);
        out.write(data, dbegin, dend - dbegin);
    }

    private byte[] unbase(Reader in) throws IOException {
        String digits = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-012345689@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVXYZ" +
            "[`abcdefhijklmpqr";
        assert digits.length() == (1 << 6);
        int[] value = new int[128];
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; ++i)
            value[i] = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); ++i)
            value[digits.charAt(i)] = i;

        int state = 0;
        int accum = 0;
        int alen = 0;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while (true) {
            int chr = in.read();
            if (chr == -1)
                throw new EOFException();
            switch (state) {
            case 0:
                switch (chr) {
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case '\t':
                case ' ':
                    state = 1;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                switch (chr) {
                case '\n':
                case '\r':
                case '\t':
                case ' ':
                    break;
                case ':':
                    state = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    state = 0;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                int v = -1, c = chr & 0x7f;
                if (c == chr) {
                    v = value[c];
                    if (v != -1) {
                        accum = (accum << 6) | v;
                        alen += 6;
                        if (alen > 8) {
                            alen -= 8;
                            baos.write((byte)(accum >>> alen));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (chr == ':') {
                    return baos.toByteArray();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static final byte RLE_MARK = (byte)0x90;

    private byte[] unrle(byte[] in) throws IOException {
        int len = in.length;
        if (in[0] == 0x90)
            throw new IOException("Incomplete RLE at beginning");
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; ++i) {
            if (in[i] == RLE_MARK) {
                ++i;
                if (i == in.length)
                    throw new IOException("Incomplete RLE at end");
                int cnt = in[i] & 0xff;
                if (cnt == 0)
                    len -= 1;
                else
                    len += cnt - 3;
            }
        }
        byte[] out = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0, o = 0; i < in.length; ++i) {
            if (in[i] == RLE_MARK) {
                ++i;
                int cnt = in[i] & 0xff;
                if (cnt == 0)
                    out[o++] = RLE_MARK;
                else {
                    byte b = out[o - 1];
                    for (int c = 1; c < cnt; ++c)
                        out[o++] = b;
                }
            }
            else {
                out[o++] = in[i];
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    private int get4(byte[] data, int offset) {
        return ((data[offset    ] & 0xff) << 24)
            |  ((data[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16)
            |  ((data[offset + 2] & 0xff) <<  8)
            |  ((data[offset + 3] & 0xff)      );
    }

    private int get2(byte[] data, int offset) {
        return ((data[offset] & 0xff) << 8)
            |  ((data[offset + 1] & 0xff));
    }

    private void crcCheck(byte[] data, int begin, int end) throws IOException {
        int crc = 0;
        for (int i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
            crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
            crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
            crc = crc ^ (data[i] & 0xff);
        }
        crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
        crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
        crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
        crc = ((crc  << 4)&0xffff) ^ (crc >> 12)*0x1021;
        int expected = get2(data, end);
        if (expected != crc)
            throw new IOException("CRC mismatch");
    }

    private void parse(byte[] in) throws IOException {
        int namelen = in[0] & 0xff;
        int headlen = namelen + 20;
        int dlen = get4(in, headlen - 8);
        int rlen = get4(in, headlen - 4);
        if (dlen < 0 || rlen < 0)
            throw new IOException("Unsigned data lenhgths not supported");
        dbegin = headlen + 2;
        dend = dbegin + dlen;
        rbegin = dend + 2;
        rend = rbegin + rlen;
        if (in.length != rend + 2 &&
            (in.length != rend + 3 || in[rend + 2] != 0))
            throw new IOException("Incorrect data size:" +
                                  " expected " + (rend + 2) +
                                  " but got " + in.length + " bytes");
        crcCheck(in, 0, headlen);
        crcCheck(in, dbegin, dend);
        crcCheck(in, rbegin, rend);
        filename = new String(in, 1, namelen, charset);
        System.err.println(filename);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new BinHexDec(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code is great. It worked perfectly for my requirement.