# Convert base64 to PDF in Java

Tags: java, pdf, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

I have a method that takes in a `String`, which is a Base64 encoding of a PDF document. How can I decode the binary back into a PDF file and then save the PDF file (or just pass back the file as a `File` object so the next program can use it).

I need to do this using Java.

Comment: might be replication of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Answer (score 21):

Try this code:

```
//Required imports
import java.io.*;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

// Code
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(encodedBytes);

File file = new File("c:/newfile.pdf");;
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file);

fop.write(decodedBytes);
fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

Comment: works just fine