# How to convert pdf hex string (generated by postgres) to byte array in java?

Tags: java, postgresql, hex, arrays

The PDF Document Hex String generated by postgres is like:

```
%PDF-1.5\015\012%\265\265\265\265\015\0121 0 obj\015\012&lt;&lt;/Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-IN) /StructTreeRoot 32 0 R/MarkInfo&lt;&lt;/Marked true&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;\015\012endobj\015\0122 0 obj\015\012&lt;&lt;/Type/Pages/Count 4/Kids[ 3 0 R 15 0 R 22 0 R 29 0 R] &gt;&gt;\015\012endobj\015\0123 0 obj\015\012&lt;&lt;/Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources&lt;&lt;/Font&lt;&lt;/F1 5 0 R/F2 7 0 R/F3 9 0 R/F4 13 0 R&gt;&gt;/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] &gt;&gt;/Annots[ 11 0 R 12 0 R] /MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group&lt;&lt;/Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB&gt;&gt;/Tabs/S/StructParents 0&gt;&gt;\015\012endobj\015\0124 0 obj\015\012&lt;&lt;/Filter/FlateDecode/Length 2984&gt;&gt;\015\012stream\015\012x\234\225Z\333\216\3436\022}o`\376A\217\322\242\315\026\305\213$ \010v\347\026\314b\263\023$\363\026\354\203\332\226\335F\273eG\266{\322\177\277UER"eK\326`\320\036\233\227b\261Xu\352\024\245\350\341\267\350\247\237\036~\375\360\345c\224\376\374s\364\376\343\207\350\375\267ww\017\237y\304\263\350\333\372\335\035\217R\370\307\243L\244L\252(/%S\320\363\362\356.\2156\370\361\313\273\273?\343\317\211\212\177O\026\322||\215\336\343\177\377Jd\374\337_\222\205\246o\377I\362\370+t\347\361\247\344\177\321\267\177\277\273\373\004+\341jn\011!3\246s\177\211?\343\310\033\033}\372\365C\024y*sOe'\244P,Oe\224\347%+\2129B\262+Btn\204h\305\204\266B\370\210\3269\214)\006c\331`\354\303\347lhO\320\357b\211\350b\332\3051\270\355\371\323\276%\013\021\357\223E\026GU"\342W\374\330\202\305w\360\027\235\260\363\011Zj\374r\271\202\030\256\300u\312T\021\256\260\256\226\333\035\212$io\021|j\263\342\032\277\253\370\320b\307v\337\232E\026"\217\217\260\346\262E?8\237\266\015\316\2212\256\232\025\366\026\324{\250\3217j\020\273z3s\214\030\022\274\254\321Up\030\376m\233\204\313xs\333&gt;\022\317]\207\332\337\243\035\022\236\305\317\370\261EI\015\310\\%\\\200\215\340\327\333\320,Ck\253\224\345V\330\261nV\011\355\221\027y\\\321\377:~\251`\215m\262P\306\350\246\363\004_\315\261\300\357\322\374\266'\301;\011hU#\360\302G\3778TM\347\246\342\212\233fY\301R\345\251g\232\333\215\373\366;\005gu@\305\016\211 \345\232\221\275f\2323\236\007{]\214\016\325L\205C
```

How to convert it to byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't `HEX` it is escaped raw `bytea`. Details about this encoding [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html).

If you want to get `HEX` from `bytea` field use `encode(bytea_field, 'HEX')`. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

UPD It could be better to `encode(bytea_field, 'base64')` and then convert `base64` string into file. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java).