# Public Key Encryption - Using Java

Tags: java, aes, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to write a asymmetric key encryption using Java (without open source libraries like Apache CXF).

I'm able to do with Apache CXF, but without open source library - I hit the error "given final block not properly padded".

I need help with a Java sample code on how this can be achieved, using the below algo's:

- data encryption algo: 
  http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc
- Key Wrap algo:
  http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5

I'm trying to encrypt the soap-header --> usernametoken.

Comment: Please can you follow that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622924/aes-error-given-final-block-not-properly-padded

Comment: Please can you follow that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622924/aes-error-given-final-block-not-properly-padded