# Java AES/CFB8/NoPadding encryption and Charset

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, aes

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt `Strings` in Java and PHP, so i use `AES/CFB8/NoPadding` that sould work on both sides.

Now my `Cryptor` works quit well with Latin Characters, as long as i set the Charset to Latin. But when i set it to UTF-8 (which is what i use in my DB), the encryption is not properly done.

Here is the output:

```
/*
* Latin (ISO-8859-1) output:
* Original: MiiiMüäöMeeʞ
* Encoded: rQ¶[ÉÐRíD
* Decoded: MiiiMüäöMee?
* 
* UTF-8 output:
* Original: MiiiMüäöMeeʞ
* Encoded: rQ�[�
* Decoded: Mii0SS1])_�EǇI�S�;�W��W?*
*/
```

Since "ʞ" is not a latin character, I understand it can not be encrypted properly. But why does UTF-8 not work?

```java
public class Cryptor {

    private Cipher cipher;
    private String secretKey = "1234567890qwertz";
    private String iv = "1234567890qwertz";

    private SecretKey keySpec;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    private Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"); // ISO-8859-1 vs. UTF-8

    public Cryptor() throws CryptingException {

        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(CHARSET), "AES");
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes(CHARSET));
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String input) throws CryptingException {

        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes(CHARSET)), CHARSET).trim();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String input) throws CryptingException {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes(CHARSET)), CHARSET).trim();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]) {

        try {
            Cryptor c = new Cryptor();
            String original = "MiiiMüäöMeeʞ";
            System.out.println("Original: " + original);
            String encrypted = c.encrypt("MiiiMüäöMeeʞ");
            System.out.println("Encoded: " + encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decoded: " + c.decrypt(encrypted));

        } catch (CryptingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class CryptingException extends RuntimeException {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7123322995084333687L;

        public CryptingException() {
            super();
        }

        public CryptingException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What character encoding is your source file? Are the characters in the `String` called `original` in your `main` method `UTF-8` or `ISO-8859-1`?

Comment: @laz In the example the OP is using a `String` so there is no encoding per-se. A `String` is `String` (internally stored in UTF-16 but that is of no consequence).

Comment: I meant the encoding of the actual `.java` file. since it isn't using the `\u` escape syntax for Unicode characters, I though there might be a chance that the `.java` file was encoded as `ISO-8859-1`. I don't think that is the problem here though after all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think turning the encrypted bytes into a `String` is a bad idea. The bytes are not valid for any encoding, they are random.

You need to encode the resulting `byte[]` to base64 to get a consistent outcome. See `sun.misc.BASE64Encoder`/`sun.misc.BASE64Decoder`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) is an example of decoding a base64 `String` to a `byte[]`, the reverse process is very similar.

You can declare the decoder/encoder and the top of the class:

```
private final BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
private final BASE64Encoder base64Encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
```

Then in your `decypt` method you need to call

```
return new String(cipher.doFinal(base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(input)), CHARSET);
```

And in your `encrypt` method

```
return base64Encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes(CHARSET)));
```

Output using UTF-8:

```
Original: MiiiMüäöMeeʞ
Encoded: clEUtlv2ALXsKYw4ivOfwQ==
Decoded: MiiiMüäöMeeʞ
```

One side note is that it's not *strictly speaking* good practice to use packages from `sun.*` as they are not part of the java spec and hence may change/vanish from version to version.

[Here](http://www.asgarli.net/2011/03/replacing-sunmiscbase64encoder-and.html) is a little article on moving to the Apache Commons Codec implementation.
This is also [a similar](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) class in the Guava API.

Comment: Your answer was right. Thanks alot! I now use DatatypeConverter for the base64 parsing and it works just fine (even with php). I'm going to post my code down here.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks alot for that answer, it really helped me alot.

Here is the working code i use to encrypt and decrypt JSON stuff in JAVA and PHP:

**JAVA**

```java
/**
 * Is used for encrypting and decrypting Strings and JSONObjects. <br>
 * The JSON Objects can then be sent to a PHP script where they can be encrypted and decrypted with the same algorithm. 
 * @throws CryptingException
 */
public class Cryptor {

    private Cipher cipher;
    private String secretKey = "1234567890qwertz";
    private String iv = "1234567890qwertz";
    private final String CIPHER_MODE = "AES/CFB8/NoPadding";

    private SecretKey keySpec;
    private IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    private Charset CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF8");

    public Cryptor() throws CryptingException {
        keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(CHARSET), "AES");
        ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes(CHARSET));
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_MODE);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param input A "AES/CFB8/NoPadding" encrypted String
     * @return The decrypted String
     * @throws CryptingException
     */
    public String decrypt(String input) throws CryptingException {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(input))); 
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param input Any String to be encrypted
     * @return An "AES/CFB8/NoPadding" encrypted String
     * @throws CryptingException
     */
    public String encrypt(String input) throws CryptingException {
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes(CHARSET))).trim();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            throw new SecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the keys and values of a JSONObject with Cryptor.encrypt(String input)
     * @param o The JSONObject to be encrypted
     * @return A JSONObject with encrypted keys and values
     */
    public JSONObject jsonObjectEncrypt(JSONObject o) {
        Iterator<?> keys = o.keys();
        JSONObject returnObject = new JSONObject();
        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            returnObject.put(this.encrypt(key), this.encrypt(o.getString(key)));
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts the keys and values of a JSONObject with Cryptor.decrypt(String input)
     * @param o The JSONObject to be decrypted
     * @return A JSONObject with decrypted keys and values
     */
    public JSONObject jsonObjectDecrypt(JSONObject o) {
        Iterator<?> keys = o.keys();
        JSONObject returnObject = new JSONObject();
        while(keys.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            if(key != null && !key.equals("")) {
                returnObject.put(this.decrypt(key), this.decrypt(o.getString(key)));
            }
        }
        return returnObject;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts keys and values of every JSONObject in a JSONArray
     * @param a The JSONArray to be encrypted
     * @return A JSONArray with encrypted keys and values
     */
    public JSONArray jsonArrayEncrypt(JSONArray a) {
        JSONArray returnArray = new JSONArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            returnArray.put(this.jsonObjectEncrypt((JSONObject)a.get(i)));
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts keys and values of every JSONObject in a JSONArray
     * @param a The JSONArray to be decrypted
     * @return A JSONArray with decrypted keys and values
     */
    public JSONArray jsonArrayDecrypt(JSONArray a) {
        JSONArray returnArray = new JSONArray();

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            returnArray.put(this.jsonObjectDecrypt((JSONObject)a.get(i)));
        }
        return returnArray;
    }

    public static void main(String Args[]) {
        try {
            Cryptor c = new Cryptor();
            String original = "MiiiMüäöMeeʞ";
            System.out.println("Original: " + original);
            String encrypted = c.encrypt(original);
            System.out.println("Encoded: " + encrypted);
            System.out.println("Decoded: " + c.decrypt(encrypted));

            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray("[{\"id\"=\" 1 ʞ3 \"},{\"id\"=\"4\"}]");

            System.out.println(c.jsonArrayDecrypt(c.jsonArrayEncrypt(arr)).getJSONObject(0).getString("id"));

        } catch (CryptingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP**

```php
<html>
    <meta charset='utf-8'> 
    <?php
    $cryptor = new Cryptor();
    echo $cryptor->decrypt($cryptor->encrypt("MiiiMüäöMeeʞ"));

    class Cryptor {
        //Use same as in java Cryptor
        private $iv = '1234567890qwertz';
        private $secretKey = '1234567890qwertz'; 

        function encrypt($input) {
            return base64_encode(
            mcrypt_encrypt( 
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                $this->secretKey,
                $input,  
                MCRYPT_MODE_CFB,
                $this->iv
            )
            );
        }

        function decrypt($input) {
          return mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            $this->secretKey, 
            base64_decode($input), 
            MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, 
            $this->iv
          );
        }

        function arrayDecrypt($array) {
            $returnArray = array();

            foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
                $newKey = $this->decrypt($key);
                $returnArray[$newKey] = $this->decrypt($value);
            }       

            return $returnArray;
        }

        function arrayEncrypt($array) {
            $returnArray = array();

            foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
                $returnArray[$this->encrypt($key)] = $this->encrypt($value);
            }       

            return $returnArray;
        }
    }
    ?>
</html>
```