# java expression to remove the dat/image part from image data

Tags: java, regex, base64, decode

I have a image data from which I need to remove the following substring

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

from the string

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD......

data:image/png;base64......
data:image/;base64
```

and then I am thinking of doing something like the following

```
   imageData = imageData.replace("regex", "");
   return Base64.decodeBase64(imageData.getBytes());
```

I want to know the regex first and also want to know whether calling

```
    imageData.getBytes()
```

will work out or not...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `.replace(regex,repl)` treats regex as "literal" (doesn't allow to
   use "`^`" to denote beginning of line, etc) - try `.replaceFirst(regex,repl)` instead
2. as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java) - try other
   Base64-decoders (which might better suit Your needs, the one below may have issues above 64KB of string length)

Aside from validation/handling - should end up with something like [this](http://ideone.com/19NH6n):

```
String imageData = "data:image/jpeg;base64,SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==";
imageData = imageData.replaceFirst("^data:image/[^;]*;base64,?","");
byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageData);
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found is to **split it at the comma** and then **save the right side** of the resulted array, to demonstrate:

```
if (imageData.contains(",")) {
    imageData = imageData.split(",")[1];
}
```

This splits the base at the comma (which returns an array) and saves the second item (what was after comma) back to the variable.*

At this point **we have the base64 without the metadata**.

Now, if you want to **save the base64 into a byte array** we can simply do so with the following code:

```
byte[] byteArr = Base64.getDecoder().decode(imageData);
```

*Base64 should not have any other commas in it so do not worry about it splitting further (but in case you want to use .split() elsewhere you can always pass a second parameter that will limit the number of resulting strings after the split, say if you want it to split only at the first comma then it would look like `.split(",", 2);`