# Passing html code from servlet to ajax through JSON

Tags: java, ajax, json, servlets

I want to put some html code to a JSONObject inside a Java servlet and send to the client using ajax, this is my html code that I want to put into a string variable called "resultado" (escaping html characters):

```
resultado += "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\">" + stringValue + "</a>";
```

This is the way I put the html code into a JsonObject (inside my servlet) through the variable that is called "resultado":

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1252");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
jsonGeneral.put("error", 0);
jsonGeneral.put("contenido", resultado);
out.print(jsonGeneral.toString());
out.close();
```

Then, the "error" attribute of $ajax() function shows me the next sentence (browser console):

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
<a href="\&quot;javascript:void(0);\&quot;">abc123...
```

This seems the html escaping is not the correct.

jsonGeneral is a JsonObject `JSONObject jsonGeneral = new JSONObject();`

and this is my code client:

```
$('#cargaDocumentoForm').ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
  success: SubmitSuccesful,
  error: function (xhr, status, error){
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")"); 
    console.log("err: " + err.Message);        
  }
```

Comment: Why are you lying about your `Content-Type`?

Comment: @SLaks Where is he doing that?

Comment: @whowantsakookie: `setContentType("text/html`

Comment: Also, what is `jsonGeneral`, and what is your client code?

Comment: @SLaks Oh I thought you were talking about User-Agent for some reason. My bad.

Comment: About the content type in my servlet I tried with "application/json; charset=utf-8", application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" but It doesn't work with none of them

Comment: I got it!

All I needed was just add the html code to a wrapper tag that I create in response time:

    var message = $("<p/>").html(responseText.contenido).text();
    $('#estado_upload').html(message);

Where "message" is a var where I get the response from the servlet (my JSON including the html code specified in my question) wrapped in a `<p/>` tag, it could be any tag (`<div/>`, `<br/>`, however).

Answer (score 0):

When I have needed to pass XML or similar in the past, we used base-64 or URL encoding on the string to avoid any need to worry about character escaping.

From a Java point of view, the following may be of use (there is too much code and too varying  a view point to make it worth me picking one, as someone will complain):
[Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java/2054226#2054226)

Ajax I've not looked into but there will be examples around somewhere.

Comment: Could you share with me some code where I could use base-64 or url encoding?

Comment: Edited to include a link

Comment: I got it!

All I needed was just add the html code to a wrapper tag that I create in response time:

    var message = $("<p/>").html(responseText.contenido).text();
    $('#estado_upload').html(message);

Where "message" is a var where I get the response from the servlet (my JSON including the html code specified in my question) wrapped in a `<p/>` tag, it could be any tag (`<div/>`, `<br/>`, however).