# how to avoid warning for the Base 64?

Tags: java

I have just tried a sample code form net it shows a warning as follows

> SimpleConvertImage.java:7: warning:com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64 is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
>   import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64; 
>                                                         ^
>
> > SimpleConvertImage.java:16: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util. Base64 is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release 
> >     String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
> >                                 ^
> >
> > > SimpleConvertImage.java:19: warning: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util .Base64 is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
> > >               byte[] bytearray =Base64.decode(base64String);
> > >                                 ^

the code is the below one

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64; 
public class SimpleConvertImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String dirName="/root/Desktop";
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,"Screenshot.png"));
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", baos);
        baos.flush();

        String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();

        byte[] bytearray =Base64.decode(base64String);

        BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
        ImageIO.write(imag, "png", new File(dirName,"snap3.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The warning says it all: You're using a class that Xerces is telling you not to use, because it's internal and proprietary and may be removed and probably smells bad too. Luckily, there are other base64 encoding/decoding options available: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: And in Java 8, it finally has official support http://stackoverflow.com/a/15646871/637889

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't use internal com.sun.* packages. If you are on v6 or greater you can use [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html). Your code would look like:

```
String base64String = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
byte[] bytearray = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
```

Answer (score 19):

You can also use: java.util.Base64
Added to Java 1.8

```
String encryptedValue = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytesToEncode));
byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedDataString);
```