# Convert Image to Base64 using Apache Commons

Tags: java, image, base64, apache-commons

I'm using BASE64Encoder of Sun Micro Systems to convert image to Base64 string. The problem is that I'm getting warnings during build which I don't want

**Java Code**..

```
     public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
    String base64String = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
    ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
    byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
    BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
    base64String = encoder.encode(imageBytes);
    bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return base64String;
    }
```

**Warnings**:

```
  [javac] /Users/lucy/dev/workspace/flsv2/src/util/BufferImage.java:53: warning: BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release 
  [javac] BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder(); 
  [javac] ^ 
  [javac] /Users/lucy/dev/workspace/flsv2/src/util/BufferImage.java:53: warning: BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release 
  [javac] BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder(); 
  [javac] ^ 
  [javac] 2 warnings
```

Is there a way to use Apache Commons in the above method so that no warnings are generated? Please Help..

Answer (score 4):

Please do not use internal `com.sun.*` packages. If you are on v6 or greater you can use [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html). Then your code will be look like below.

```
String base64String = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(baos.toByteArray());
byte[] bytearray = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64String);
```

Or,

You can also use: `java.util.Base64` which is added in Java `1.8`

```
String base64String = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytesToEncode));
byte[] decordedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String);
```

Or, you can make a method calling procedure in `apache commons` that is given below

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

public String decode(String s) {
    return StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(s));
}
public String encode(String s) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(s));
}
```

### Resource Link:

1. [org.apache.commons.codec.binary.base64 Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/codec/binary/base64-binary/org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64-example/)
2. [how to avoid warning for the Base 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904682/how-to-avoid-warning-for-the-base-64)