# ClassNotFoundException / NoClassDefError com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/util/Base64 in WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly

Got following exception in WildFly:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/util/Base64

How to solve this dependency in WildFly?

Comment: do you have xerces.jar as dependency ?

Comment: I have wildfly module <module name="org.apache.xerces"/> as dependency but it looks for the com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/util/Base64 in jdk and shows this error. I wonder how to resolve this in WidFly since the class itself in jdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/util/Base64 is internal and proprietary and may be removed and probably, used different class which has no class loading issue.
Applied the solution mentioned here: [how to avoid warning for the Base 64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904682/how-to-avoid-warning-for-the-base-64)

For Java 8, [Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)