# Trying to serve image stored in GAE Datastore originally created by canvas.toDataURL()

Tags: java, javascript, image, google-app-engine, canvas

I have a canvas painted by the user.

In the JavaScript I do:

```
var data = canvas.toDataURL().substr(22);

// snipped code that sets up xhr POST to "d/"

var params = "img=" + encodeURIComponent(data);
xhr.send(params);
```

I substr(22) to get rid of "data:image/png;base64,"

Then in app engine I do:

```
doodle.setProperty("img", new Text(req.getParameter("img")));
```

So I am setting the img property of the doodle Entity to the canvas.toDataURL().substr(22)

Now, when I want to retrieve the image, I do:

```
if (debugimg) {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().print(((Text)groove.getProperty("img")).getValue());
}
else {
     resp.setContentType("image/png;base64");
     resp.getWriter().print(((Text)groove.getProperty("img")).getValue());
}
```

But for the life of me, the image never comes up.

Here is an example. I drew this, and can save it and render it in JavaScript.

https://yougotadoodle.appspot.com/d.jsp?id=1483002

If I use debugimg, this is what is being saved:

http://yougotadoodle.appspot.com/d?id=1483002&img=true&debugimg=true

But when I try to serve it with setContentType("image/png;base64") or even just "image/png" you get a broken picture:

http://yougotadoodle.appspot.com/d?id=1483002&img=true

I have tried a few different things, including not substr(22)ing it. Any ideas?

I tried using a Blob(), so storing it like this:

```
doodle.setProperty("img", new Blob(req.getParameter("img").getBytes()));
```

and reading it like this:

```
resp.getWriter().print(((Blob)groove.getProperty("img")).getBytes());
```

But that seemed to spit out somethign like this:

```
[B@1f11e0f
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decode this string before serving it as `image/png` because it is the Base64 encoded version.

I tested it locally in Python and your `Hello SO!` worked perfectly after decoding the given string. I'm not sure how to do it in Java but it should be [fairly easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Here are three code snippets that have worked for me on the JS side (jpg) through the put to a blob property. May not be optimal, but it does work. HTH. -stevep

Create canvas render:

```
imgFinalData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg', 1.0);
```

Setup variable for POST to GAE:

```
f64 = imgFinalData.substr(imgFinalData.indexOf(',')+1).toString();
```

Post to GAE (fd is an array used to store mutiple POST vars):

```
fd.push('bytes=' + escape(f64));
//Here is the call with fd that handles the post:
postXmlHttpRequest(url, fd.join('&'), handlePostFinal);
```

One the GAE side (Python):

Property that stores POST data (line from entity class):

bytes = db.BlobProperty(required=True, indexed=False)

How the post data is processed b/4 put:

data = urllib.unquote(self.request.get('bytes'))

data = data.replace(' ','+')

bytes = base64.b64decode(data + '=' * (4 - len(data) % 4))

Property line inside the entity statement for put:

bytes = db.Blob(bytes),