# Getting no output for BASE64Encoder()

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-3.0

I have tried a lot tested each step of my program, i get output but when i am testing BASE64Encoder() line it is not working,i stuck completely even eclipse not showing any error on BASE64Encoder() line ,I want your help how to get rid of this problem ,
code is given below

```
private void findMeaning(HttpServletResponse resp,String plainText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
    InvalidKeySpecException, 
    NoSuchPaddingException, 
    InvalidKeyException,
    InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
    UnsupportedEncodingException, 
    IllegalBlockSizeException, 
    BadPaddingException, 
    IOException{ 
        String text = plainText;
        String key="ezeon8547";
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);//working
        SecretKey key1 = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);    //working    
         // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
        AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

        ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key1.getAlgorithm());//working
        ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key1, paramSpec);//working      
        String charSet="UTF-8";       
        byte[] in = text.getBytes(charSet);//working
        byte[] out = ecipher.doFinal(in);//working

        String encStr=new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(out);//unknown error
          sendResponse(resp, "Pincode city:" +encStr);//not get output
    }
```

Comment: It works for me, and yes I know I shouldn't be using it. Do you get an 'unknown error' meaning an exception, and if so what? or do you just get an empty String?

Comment: I tested out each line working properly but when I want string value encStr it not works for me unknown error not output even no exception problem showing in code @EJP

Comment: You're not being clear. What does 'unknown error' mean? Do you get the 'Pincode city:' part of the output? This mightn't be a Base64 problem at all, just an I/O problem.

Comment: @EJP when i run this program in desktop by removing httpservletresponse it is working and encrypting but when i deploy this in google appengine and providing the string it stucks no output

Answer (score 2):

The solution is probably solved by not using any of the Sun classes. The Sun classes (i.e those with `sun.*` package names distributed with the JRE) are not part of the Java API and should not be used. Use either Guava, Apache Commons Codec or Bouncy Castle lightweight API to perform the decoding.

For example, use [`org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29).

If you want to stick to the normal Java API, use either `java.util.Base64` (Java 8 onwards) or use up `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` according to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469695/589259).

Comment: What I can write in place of sun inner class @owlstead

Comment: Put in a link to the Apache Codec in the answer. Guava is case sensitive and Bouncy is a very large library. The Java classes are either XML specific or are only available from Java 8 onwards.

Comment: They are Sun classes, but they are not 'inner classes'.

Comment: @EJP Hmm, yeah. Um. You are right of course. Should I call them Sun implementation classes? Normally I would just say you should not use `sun.*` classes, but Sun has unhelpfully created a few API's with `sun.*` packages, although those are not distributed with the JRE.

Comment: They're called sun.* classes in the Javadoc that tells you not to use them.

Comment: @owlstead I think you're confusing internal `sun` packages with libraries distributed under `com.sun` -- the latter are OK to use.

Comment: @TomG Nice catch, thanks. It probably indicates that I should *definitely* go to sleep ;)