# Saving binary data in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a problem with saving a binary representation of a file to a file...
Let me show you my pain:

Everything starts with a file, file.pdf
Then the file is send via POST to a website with some additional data:

```
curl --data "sector=4&name=John&surname=Smith&email=john@smith.com&isocode=PL&theFile=$(cat file.pdf | base64)" http://localhost/awesomeUpload
```

then the data is received and decoded:

```
var decoded = BinaryDecode(data.theFile, "Base64");
```

then I attempt to save it by:

```
var theFilePath = ExpandPath("/localserver/temp/theFile.pdf");
fileWrite(theFilePath , data.theFile);
```

or:

```
var file_output_steam = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream").init(theFilePath);
    file_output_steam.write(data.theFile);
    file_output_steam.close();
```

My files does not match ;(

the original one looks like

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pl-PL) /StructTreeRoot 13 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 10 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
```

where as the copy that went through ColdFusion looks like:

```
%PDF-1.5
%µµµµ
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pl-PL) /StructTreeRoot 13 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>> B™[™ŘšBŚŘšBŹŐ\KÔYŮ\ËĐŰÝ[ťKŇÚYÖČČ—H€Đ¦VćFö& ĐŁ2ö& ĐŁĂÂőG—RővRő&VçB""ő&W6÷W&6W3ĂÂôföçCĂÂôcR"ôc"#ŕ˝AÉ˝ŤM•Ńl˝A˝Q•áĐ˝%µ…ť•˝%µ…ť•˝%µ…ť•%t€>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>B™[™ŘšBŤŘšBŹŃš[\‹Ń›]QXŰŮKÓ[™ÝMŚOŹBśÝ™X[CBž'cłB°Ś!8Ě1Ď]CsôŘQ&‰2  PäV˝ëËöĽ¨QŰge•ź
ďÂŃ,đť@"aKR•˘<1™[ä¸
(ÄňĄyoâ9S\Śĺ <ę8I±D¬‰#…Ć”ťLé‘Ř§÷ÍnU|WĹ¸‰t`ýuşąĽ\hlu&âĂ7ß
ů"Ĺ\Ŕ>pÇč÷÷.°ß’Ř——•‹ĚB™[™Ý™X[CB™[™ŘšBŤHŘšBŹŐ\KŃ›ŰťÔÝXť\KŐ\LĐ\ŮQ›ŰťĐPŃQJĐŘ[XśšKŃ[ŰŮ[™ËŇY[ť]KRŃ\ŘŮ[™[ť›ŰťČ
‹ŐŐ[šXŰŮHŚŹŹB™[™ŘšBŤŘšB–Č
Č—HB™[™ŘšBŤČŘšBŹĐ\ŮQ›ŰťĐPŃQJĐŘ[XśšKÔÝXť\KĐŇQ›Űť\L‹Ő\KŃ›ŰťĐŇQŃŇQX\ŇY[ť]KŃČLĐŇQŢ\Ý[R[™›Č‹Ń›Űť\ŘÜš\ÜH‹ŐČŚŕĐ¦VćFö& ĐŁ‚ö& ĐŁĂÂô÷&FW&–ćr„–FVçF—G’’ő&Vv—7G'’„Fö&R’ő7WĆVÖVçBăŕĐ¦VćFö& ĐŁ’ö& ĐŁĂÂőG—RôföçDFW67&—F÷"ôföçDć
```

please help

Comment: Instead of `filewrite()`, have you tried serving it right out with `<cfcontent>` and see if it works?

Comment: It's an output tag and I want to write to the file.

Comment: It seems to me more like a pure Java issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java When I used sun.misc.BASE64Decoder the copy was much closer to the original, still however file was broken.