# Send a hash value over soap

Tags: java, xml, soap, hash, md5

Is it possible to send an MD5 hash computed String over SOAP?

Whenever I do something like `String key = md5(something)`
 and try to send key via a Java SOAP client, I always get the error message

> Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xsomething) was found in the element content of the document.

I'am aware that computing md5 on a string presumably produces invalid XML characters. The Question is to know whether there is a way let that go through anyway.

I am using the `MessageDisgest` class of Java to compute MD5 strings.

Best regards.

Edmond

Comment: Without seeing what are you exactly doing with java beans and how do you convert it into xml, it is hard to advise something.

Comment: BTW, this is not about `soap`, it is about `xml` generally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert the MD5 byte array to hex string representation or encode it using Base64. Both conversions result in a simple string which can be included in XML without (XML)encoding.

[Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

[Convert from byte array to hex string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java)

Comment: Thank you @icza for the quick answer. I have tried 2 alternatives based on the second link you have provided [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java) which are the javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter and the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex. It is very stunning as the both of them produces different outputs. The first one has its letters in lower case while the other has its letters in upper case. So wo is telling the truth here.

Comment: In hex representation lower or upper case digits do not have meaning, `'a'` is the same as `'A'`. You can convert from one form to the other using `String.toLowerCase()` and `String.toUpperCase()`.