# Deserializable exception : local class is not compatible cause of serialVersionID

Tags: java, spring, exception, serialization, stream

Here is my code:

```
MyOwnObject deserializedObject = null;
try{
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObject.getBytes());
    ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    deserializedObject = (MyOwnObject)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

someMapper.insert(deserializedObject);
```

PS: serializedObject is a string which i get from serialization process before, and it's working well i think.

The code throws an exception:

```
local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 1360826667802527544, local class serialVersionUID = 1360826667806852920
```

And in the stacktrace there's something about the type Integer of some attribute in my object.

UPDATE:
serializeObject is a string,from this code:

```
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
    so.writeObject(myObject);
    so.flush();
    serializedObject = bo.toString();
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

ANSWER:

```
    //Serialization from object to string
    String serializedObject="";
    try{
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        oos.flush();
        serializedObject = new String(Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
        oos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Deserialization from string to object
    MyOwnObject deserializedObject = null;
    try{
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(serializedObject.getBytes());
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        deserializedObject = (MyOwnObject)ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

From here,i can use deserializedObject as an object,and it worked well!

Comment: What is and how do you create `serializedObject`?

Comment: it's from
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new
    ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
    so.writeObject(myObject);
    so.flush();
    serializedObject = bo.toString();

Comment: *serializedObject is a string*: that's probably the problem. objects are serialized to bytes, not characters. Don't transform binary bytes to a String.

Comment: @NicoPratama You should edit your question with the details of `serializedObject` instead of adding it in a comment.

Comment: It's a wrong approach. But see my edited answer, at the end I mention how to create a `String` from the serialized object.

Comment: But,the string that will be produced from serialization will not be readable right?I never use hex string or base64 before,which one is better?Thanks for your response!:)

Comment: "serializedObject is a string" This is already wrong. `String` is not a container for binary data. You should save it in a `byte[]` array, unless you hex- or base64-encode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you create your `serializedObject`.

You use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. You shouldn't call `toString()` on it. Instead call its `toByteArray()` method to get the underlying data as a byte array, and you can use that to create your `ByteArrayInputStream` and it will work.

Example:

```
// Serialization
ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
so.writeObject(myObject);
so.flush();
byte[] serializedObject = bo.toByteArray();

// Deserialization
MyOwnObject deserializedObject = null;
try {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObject);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
    deserializedObject = (MyOwnObject)ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A serialized object is a sequence of bytes (a byte array) and not a sequence of characters. You cannot create a `String` from the bytes of a serialized object, because it may not contain valid unicode codepoints for example.

If you really need to represent the serialized object as a `String`, try representing the byte array in [hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java) or use [base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java).

Comment: i've seen uses of base64 for this problem everywhere,is it the best option?i'm going to send the serializedObject string onto a queue (JMS w/ Apache ActiveMQ) and then later consume it and rebuild an object for further uses..

Comment: In this case check the documentation of the software/code what is expected, and in this case you obviously have no choice but to create the form that is required.

Comment: If you will be the one that reads the message and deserialize the object, then the decision is in your hand. Both method (hex string and base64) will work in any case. If your object is small, hex string is faster. If you object is large, base64 produces smaller String. So you decide.

Comment: I use base 64,even though the string sent through MQ is unreadable and similar to some hash code,but what important is that the string can be sent and can be converted back to an object.. thanks @icza!

Answer (score 1):

besides base64, you can use hex string also!i always use it when i encounter a similar problems!