# Android base64.decode() into existing byte array

Tags: android, memory, bitmap, base64

On Android, I'm using Base64.decode() method. It has several variants, but all of them decode the given base64 input into a newly created byte array.

Since I need to call this a lot with big inputs, it allocates a lot of memory and causes frequent GC.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to pass an existing byte array to the method, or alternative techniques, so that it puts the result inside the existing byte array and avoid allocating memory for a new one.
That would be similar to the use of options.inBitmap in BitmapFactory when creating a bitmap in order to reuse an existing bitmap.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I suggest you create your own Base64 decoder. You can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10736154/3410697