# Unable to listen the SQS messages in java SqsListener produced from the python using boto SDK

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I am sending the message using the boto SDK to Amazon-SQS. Whatever the message I send it has to listen using the SqsListener written in java.When I send message I am not able to get the exact message what I have send from the producer class written in python. In SQSListener class I just tried to print the message what I have got. I am getting the encrypted form of message instead of actual message.

**Actual message:**
Sample message

**Received Message**
U2FtcGxlIG1lc3NhZ2U=

The **producer** class written in the python is:

```
from boto import sqs
import json
from boto.sqs.message import Message 

conn = sqs.connect_to_region('XXXXX', aws_access_key_id='XXXXXXXXXXXX', aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
queueInstance = conn.get_queue('sample')
try:
   message = Message()    
   message.set_body("testing sample")
   queueInstance.write(message)
except Exception, error:
   print error
```

The Receiver SQSListener class is:

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;


public class SQSMessageLisner implements MessageListener {

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside ON MESSAGE");
        //System.out.println(message.get);
        String stringMessage = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
        System.out.println(stringMessage);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The sending the receiving of messages are written in same SDK's are working fine. Coming to sending from python and listening in java leads to this problem. Please help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a base64 encoded message in your receiver. You need to decode it, as described here [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Your other option is to use boto.sqs.message.RawMessage in python instead of TextMessage, which will not be encoded.