# I have Base64 content of an xml file.I want to decode that and save the content of file to a string rather than saving in external file

Tags: java

I have Base64 content of an xml file.I want to decode that and save the content of file to a string rather than saving in external file.
Can anyone suggest this.
Please see the following thing

### **Base64 Encoded Format**

```
PD94bUeXBlPmVJQSBjaGFuZ2VzPC9GaWxlVHlwZT4NCiAgICA8RmlsZURhdGU+=
```

### **File Content**

```
<DATA>
  <Table>
    <LotNo>50700022611201413280</LotNo>
    <FileFrom>CAMS Repository Services Limited</FileFrom>
    <NoOfRec>2</NoOfRec>
    <FileType>eIA partial</FileType>
    <FileDate>26/11/2014 13:28:02</FileDate>
    <FileFromCode>5</FileFromCode>
    <FileToCode>7</FileToCode>
    <FileTypeCode>301</FileTypeCode>
  </Table>
</Data>
```

**I am using following code for this**

```
String outFnm="PD94bUeXBlPmVJQSBjaGFuZ2VzPC9GaWxlVHlwZT4NCiAgICA8RmlsZURhdGU+=";
    byte[] b1=outFnm.getBytes();
        byte[] bFile=Base64.decodeBase64(b1);
        //System.out.println(b1.toString());
            //Integer bFile2=Integer.parseInt(bFile);
        System.out.println(b1);
        System.out.println(bFile.toString());   
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/test.txt");
        fos.write(bFile);
        fos.close();
```

But I **don't want** to use a **seperate file** to store that. I **want** a **string variable** which stores the "test.txt" contents.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode Base64 data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String has a constructor that takes a byte array. Simply do

```
String myString = new String(bFile)
```

Comment: @sailakshmi If the response satisfies you, please remember to mark it as correct (the green tick) for the others too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using java 8, you can do like

```
import java.util.Base64;

byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
String s = new String(decoded);
```

Here `encoded` is the byte[] array of base64 string.

```
String base64String = "YOUR-BASE64";
byte[] encoded = base64String.getBytes();
```