# Base64 from ByteArray

Tags: android, base64, jpeg

I have tried to use code below in my application to encode a `jpg` file to `Base64`.

```
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(imagelocation);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] bytes;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bytes = output.toByteArray();
    String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.d(TAG, encodedString);
```

Output is following:

```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```

Already tried to put this code into several decoders, but cannot convert this code back to a picture. What should be the problem?

Comment: Read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java?rq=1

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, encodedString);` That will not print the whole string. Only the begin of it. So your base64 is not complete. Check with string length. Are you seeing only a part of the image? Write the string to a file and then open that file and copy paste the contents in the decoder.

Comment: You have two catch blocks in your code. That is ok. But if there is a catch you continue with your code as if there was not a catch. Better return and give a toast.

Comment: For the rest your code looks ok. But the file will be twice in memory as you see. You could do away with the byte output stream too and just declare a byte [] bytes of the right file size. And read directly in it. Then the file will be in memory only once.

Comment: You could also try with a very small jpg file so the string gets completely printed in the log. Try your avatar ;-).

Comment: @greenapps: Thanks! Is there maybe logging tools that can write the whole string instead of using files. Copying from `logcat` to a converter is much more faster, than browsing files.