# Is there any data lost in Java if I convert Binary data to a String and back?

Tags: java, type-conversion, binaryfiles, binary-data, raw-data

I have a messaging class in my java program that only uses `String` values and never any `binary` data.

I want to send a `rpm` file, so basically `binary` data through this messaging class to a `receiver`.

I know this can be done by converting the `binary` data to a `String` on the `messaging` end and then back to a `binary` file on the `receiving` end.

However my question is, will any data be lost between converting my `binary` file to a `String` then back to `binary data` to save as a `binary` file, or will the data be retained through all conversions?

Comment: That depends; how are you intending to *encode* the binary data?

Comment: Provided that you don'y use some exotic implementation, you won't lose anything. Have a look at Base64 for instance, that enables you to convert byte arrays to String and vice versa : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i never thought of that part of the design yet, what are my options?

Comment: @Berger that is an excellent library you linked too, however in my project we do not have apache commons. Can I still do this manually in java?

Comment: To add to Elliott's comment, the basic idea here is that data may be lost if you choose an encoding which can't handle the range of characters in your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well its an `rpm` file on RHEL for a 32 bit arch. Am not sure then what might be the best encoding to use.

Comment: @jgr208 : look here for probably available implementations, or even custom ones : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469695/decode-base64-data-in-java

Comment: +1 I work with RHEL files (and other CAD files).  Actually, I work with code which allows uploading and viewing these files in Java.

Comment: Can you modify the messaging class? Why does it support only Strings if you intend to send non-text data?

Comment: @Kayaman no I can not that classes design is set in stone. It was a requirement that changed.

Comment: Isn't it amazing how designs are always "set in stone", but requirements always change? What would you do if it was completely impossible to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binary data means `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`. And java uses internally Unicode for text: `String, char, Reader, Writer`.

Hence one should only convert binary data that represents text, and also specify the encoding of that binary data:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Non-text data should not be converted, as it may be illegal for the specific encoding, especially for the multibyte encoding UTF-8.
Also the conversion to Unicode is an unnecessary inefficiency. For instance java `char` is two bytes (UTF-16 encoded).

Better use a `ByteArrayInputStream, ByteArrayOutputStream, ByteBuffer` for some purposes. Never String. When obstinate, then use `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1`.

Comment: I should have mentioned **Base64** to encode the binary data to text, it pumps up the size and speed to 4/3 and then a char is 2 bytes, so normally 8/3. For an **rpm** this seemed too bad.